# Why does the JVM still not support tail-call optimization?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, optimization, jvm, tail-call-optimization

Two years after [does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations), there seems to be a [prototype](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/mlvm-dev/2009-January/000331.html) [implementation](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Papers/Schwaighofer09Master/) and [MLVM](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/subprojects.html) has listed the feature as "proto 80%" for some time now.

Is there no active interest from Sun's/Oracle's side in supporting tail calls or is it just that tail calls are "[...] *fated to come in second place on every feature priority list* [...]" as mentioned at the [JVM Language Summit](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/Why_Tailcalls)?

I would be really interested if someone has tested a MLVM build and could share some impressions of how well it works (if at all).

***Update:*** *Note that some VMs like [Avian](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/) support proper tail-calls without any issues.*

Comment: With the reported exodus of Sun people from Oracle, I would not expect that _any_ of the current projects continue unless explicitly said so from Oracle :(

Comment: Note that your accepted answer is completely wrong. There is no fundamental conflict between tail call optimization and OOP and, of course, several languages like OCaml and F# have both OOP and TCO.

Comment: Well, calling OCaml and F# OOP languages is a bad joke in the first place. But yes, OOP and TCO have not much in common, except the fact that the runtime has to check that the method being optimized is not overridden/subclassed somewhere else.

Comment: +1 Coming from a C background, I always assumed that TCO was a given in any modern JVM. It never occurred to me to actually check and when I did the results were surprising...

Comment: @soc: "except the fact that the runtime has to check that the method being optimized is not overridden/subclassed somewhere else". Your "fact" is complete nonsense.

Comment: @soc: Note that your accepted answer is wrong for the reasons I explained in my comment beneath it.

Comment: With Scala being an object-functional language that runs on the JVM and performs tail call optimization, I believe most of what's said here is wrong and void?

Comment: Scala's compiler does all the hard work for you, not the JVM. But because it is at compile-time, only the most simplest tail recursive scenarios can be optimized (e. g. anything involving dynamic dispatch, non-final methods, mutually recursive tail calls, etc). There are runtimes out there which support the “full level” of tail recursion, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the JVM prevent tail call optimizations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Diagnosing Java Code:  Improving the Performance of Your Java Code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-diag8.html) ([alt](http://web.archive.org/web/20120506085636/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-diag8/index.html)) explains why the JVM does not support tail-call optimization.

> But although it is well known how to automatically transform a tail-recursive function into a simple loop, the Java specification doesn't require that this transformation be made. Presumably, one reason it is not a requirement is that, in general, the transformation can't be made statically in an object-oriented language. Instead, the transformation from tail-recursive function to simple loop must be done dynamically by a JIT compiler.

It then gives an example of Java code that won't transform.

> So, as the example in Listing 3 shows, we cannot expect static compilers to perform transformation of tail recursion on Java code while preserving the semantics of the language. Instead, we must rely on dynamic compilation by the JIT. Depending on the JVM, the JIT may or may not do this.

Then it gives a test you can use to figure out if your JIT does this.

Naturally, since this is an IBM paper, it includes a plug:

> I ran this program with a couple of
>   the Java SDKs, and the results were
>   surprising. Running on Sun's Hotspot
>   JVM for version 1.3 reveals that
>   Hotspot doesn't perform the
>   transformation. At default settings,
>   the stack space is exhausted in less
>   than a second on my machine.  On the
>   other hand, IBM's JVM for version 1.3
>   purrs along without a problem,
>   indicating that it does transform the
>   code in this way.

Comment: FWIW, tail calls are not just about self-recursive functions as he implies. Tail calls are any function calls that appear in tail position. They do not have to be calls to self and they do not have to be calls to statically known locations (e.g. they can be virtual method calls). The problem he describes is a non-issue if tail call optimization is done properly in the general case and, consequently, his example works perfectly in object oriented languages that support tail calls (e.g. OCaml and F#).

Comment: "must be done dynamically by a JIT compiler" which means it must be done by the JVM itself rather than the Java compiler. But the OP is asking about the JVM.

Comment: "in general, the transformation can't be made statically in an object-oriented language." This is a quote of course, but every time I see such excuse I would like to ask about numbers -- because I wouldn't be surprised if in practice in majority of cases it could be established at compile time.

Comment: The link to the cited article is now broken, though Google does have it cached. More importantly, the author's reasoning is faulty. The example given *could* be tail-call optimized, using static and *not* just dynamic compilation, if only the compiler inserted an `instanceof` check to see if `this` is an `Example` object (rather than a subclass of `Example`).

Comment: For reference, the test class from the paper is `public class TailRecursionTest { private static int loop(int i) { return loop(i); } public static void main(String[] args) { loop(0); } }`

Comment: just link to webarchive http://web.archive.org/web/20120506085636/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-diag8/index.html

Comment: @greenoldman In principle, tail call optimization (TCO) can always be done: Just pop local variables and parameters from the stack, push parameters for the tail call, make sure you keep the return address, and JMP instead of JSR to the new function. You lose the caller's data on the stack, so exception traces become less informative, so not doing this can be justified as a conscious decision. Also, unfortunate implementation choices can prevent anything from being doable.

Answer (score 34):

One reason I've seen in the past for not implementing TCO (and it being seen as difficult) in Java is that the permission model in the JVM is stack-sensitive and thus tail-calls must handle the security aspects.

I believe this was shown to not be an obstacle by Clements and Felleisen [1] [2] and I'm pretty sure the MLVM patch mentioned in the question deals with it as well.

I realize this does not answer your question; just adding interesting information.

1. http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/esop2003-cf.pdf
2. http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/cf-toplas04.pdf

Comment: +1. Listen questions/responses at the end of this presentation of Brian Goetz https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y5Pv4yN0b0&t=3739

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps you know this already, but the feature is not as trivial as it may sound since the Java language actually exposes the stack trace to the programmer.

Consider the following program:

```
public class Test {

    public static String f() {
        String s = Math.random() > .5 ? f() : g();
        return s;
    }

    public static String g() {
        if (Math.random() > .9) {
            StackTraceElement[] ste = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
            return ste[ste.length / 2].getMethodName();
        }
        return f();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f());
    }
}
```

Even though this has a "tail-call" it may not be optimized. (If it *is* optimized, it still requires book-keeping of the entire call-stack since the semantics of the program relies on it.)

Basically, this means that it's hard to support this while still being backward compatible.

Comment: Solution is easy. Keep a flag for functions that finger their stack (like g), and do not tailcall optimize any that call them.

Comment: Found the mistake in your thought: "requires book-keeping of the entire call-stack since the semantics of the program relies on it". :-) It's like the new "suppressed Exceptions". Programs relying on such things are bound to break. In my opinion the behavior of the program is absolutely correct: Throwing away stack frames is the thing tail calls are all about.

Comment: @Marco, but just about any method could throw an exception, from which the entire call-stack is bound to be available, right? Besides, you can't decide in advance which methods will indirectly call `g` in this case... think about polymorphism and reflection for instance.

Comment: @soc, I'm not quite sure I follow you. What is suppressed exceptions?

Comment: It is a side-effect caused by the addition of ARM in Java 7. It is an example that you can't rely on such things you showed above.

Comment: @soc, Just because *some* new features breaks some backward-compatibility, doesn't mean that it doesn't make any difference if other features breaks backward compatibility too... No, there is no mistake in my answer. The fact that the stack-trace is exposed in the API poses a problem for (soft) tail-call recursion and is one (of many) reasons [why such feature is troublesome to add](http://blogs.sun.com/jrose/entry/tail_calls_in_the_vm).

Comment: It does not break, because there is nothing to be broken. There is no promise that stacktraces don't change and they _do_ change from time to time (as I have shown above). Anyone relying on a certain stacktrace format is just wrong.

Comment: Fortunately, Sun is not as lunatic as you guys are. Behavior comparability is very important. Language spec is not everything.

Comment: @irreputable: Look at the facts before calling other people lunatic. *hint* ARM in Java 7.

Comment: @soc: "It is a side-effect caused by the addition of ARM in Java 7". Wow, that's really interesting.

Comment: "the fact that the language exposes the call-stack makes it hard to implement this": does the language require that the stack-trace returned by `getStackTrace()` from a method `x()` that the source code shows is called from a method `y()` also shows that `x()` was called from `y()`? Becasue if there is some freedom there is no real issue.

Comment: This is merely a matter of wording the spec of a single method, from "gives you all stack frames" to "gives you all active stackframes, leaving out the ones obsoleted by tail calls". Furthermore, one could make it a command line switch or a system property whether tail-call is honoured.

Comment: This does not preclude proper tail calls.  An faster alternative implementation (compared to re-using the current stack frame) performs the call as normal, but allows garbage collection of uneccessary stack frames later on.

Comment: How would the runtime figure out whether a stack frame is unnecessary?

Answer (score 12):

Java is the least functional language you could possibly imagine (well, OK, [perhaps not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS)!) but this would be a great advantage for JVM languages, like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org), which are.

My observations are that making the JVM a platform for other languages has never seemed to be at the top of the priority list for Sun and I guess, now for Oracle.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - I wrote a program to predict whether any given program would halt in a finite amount of time. It took me *ages*!

Comment: The first BASICs I used didn't have functions, but rather GOSUB and RETURN.  I don't think LOLCODE is very functional, either (and you can take that in two senses).

Comment: @David, functional != has functions.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen:  No, but it is kind of a prerequisite, wouldn't you say?

Comment: OP didn't use the word Java, just JVM.

Comment: "making the JVM a platform for other languages has never seemed to be at the top of the priority list for Sun". They put considerably more effort into making the JVM a platform for dynamic languages than they did for functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Java problem... it's one of the JVM. Java is just the grand-grand-ol'-pa of JVM languages.

Making a TCO is jumping to the next Stack Frame while deleting the current one, in between the running program and current stack calling vars should be somewhere else... ;)

The best way would be to have a new special call opcode for a jump-call in other frames that makes the stuff. They already did that for the virtual call. Not really a problem in interpretation, JIT perhaps rises other problems, and the JVM is bloated enough.

In Java or other languages, as there no proper TCO, the other way is trampolining, but it adds a lot of code. Or using specific exceptions, but it messes a lot. And it is in your code, but not in others' libraries...

Ah! If Rich Hickey added a (recur...) stuff (it's not a function), it's because of lack of real TCO, he doesn't want people to think there was one. He could very easily make an automatic TCO in an internal tail call. It also helps to detect bad tail calls that are not in tail position.

There's also a (trampoline...) stuff for external TCO, but it's messy (as a trampoline), and is quite not used except in awful stack situations.

But yes, a lot of VM manage TCO. I've heard that CLR will. I've even seen a paying JVM that manages it (a time ago, don't remember...)

Trampolining example in js: https://codeinjavascript.com/2020/06/13/tail-call-optimization-tco/

An old Thesis on TCO on HotSpot VM with Frame overwrite: https://ssw.jku.at/Research/Papers/Schwaighofer09Master/schwaighofer09master.pdf