# Does Java support tail recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the JVM still not support tail-call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616483/why-does-the-jvm-still-not-support-tail-call-optimization)

I see so many different answers online, so I thought I'd ask the experts.

Comment: The experts have been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616483/why-does-the-jvm-still-not-support-tail-call-optimization

Comment: So you asked the Java development mailing list?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations

Comment: In generally, what is an elegant recursive solution in a functional language is more naturally/performant as a loop in Java.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  Those linked questions concern the JVM or Scala, not Java in particular.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is difference between tail recursion and tail recursion optimization. Tail recursion is supported by java because there is nothing special in it, tail recursion optimization is not supported.