# tail Recursion multiplication using BigInteger

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to modify my multiplication by addition function to incorporate two things:-

(1) tail recursion
(2) bigIntegers

However, for large integers I am still struggling since I got a stack overflow. I even tried to run my program using a -Xss switch to expand the stack but still no luck. I think there is something wrong with my method. Appreciate any advice.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-java -->
public static BigInteger multiRecursive(int multiplicand, int multiplier) {
    return multiTailRecursive(multiplicand, multiplier, multiplicand);
}

public static BigInteger multiTailRecursive(int multiplicand, int multiplier, int result){      
    if (multiplicand == 0 || multiplier == 0) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    }
    if (multiplier == 1) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(result);
    }

    return multiTailRecursive(multiplicand, multiplier - 1, result + multiplicand);
}
```

Comment: Why? Did you know Java does not support [tail recursion optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401090/2970947)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack overflows from deep recursion in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860550/stack-overflows-from-deep-recursion-in-java)

Comment: No I actually didn't know that, however, when I used a regular recursion method without the tail recursion and I used the Xss switch to run the program I was able to multiply 50000 * 50000 recursively and get a result...however, now the function returns a negative number....am guessing a stack overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been discussed at
[Stack overflows from deep recursion in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860550/stack-overflows-from-deep-recursion-in-java):

> Increasing the stack size will only serve as a temporary bandage ... what you really want is tail call elimination, and Java does not have this for various reasons.

Comment: Are my functions correct though? and why if I increase the stack size I still get an error?