# How is recursion implemented in Java

Tags: java, recursion

How is recursion implemented in Java? My question is about what happens behind when a recusrsive method is executed in Java. I vaguely understand that it uses the Stack, but i am looking for a clear explanation with example.

Comment: Please try the following : http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/techniques/recursion_how.shtml

Comment: Its "The Stack" not Stacks ;)

Comment: @AmitBhargava Link explains what a recursion is, but i am looking for how it is implemented in Java

Comment: You may want to check out the link below
https://rawisglenn.medium.com/recursion-explained-with-inception-movie-analogy-c185fdad9bb5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recursion isn't handled much differently in Java than in other (imperative) languages.

There's [a stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) which holds a stack frame for every method invocation. That stack is the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (or simply just "stack", when the context makes it clear what is meant). The element on the stack are called "stack frames".

A stack frame holds the method arguments passed in and the local variables of a method invocation (and possibly some other data, such as the return address).

When a method invokes itself (or, in fact, *any* method) then a new stack frame is created for the parameters and local variables of the newly-called method.

During the method execution the code can *only* access the values in the *current* (i.e. top-most) stack frame.

This way a single (local) variable can seemingly have many different values at the same time.

Recursion isn't handled any other way than normal method calls, except that multiple stack frames will represent invocations of the same method at the same time.

Comment: I was going to say "Except for the tail call recursion optimisation." but apparently the Java VM still doesn't support it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616483/why-does-the-jvm-still-not-support-tail-call-optimization

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: simply speaking tail recursion optimization is "simply" re-using the current stack frame when the compiler/runtime realizes that it's no longer needed except for the return address. It doesn't fundamentally change the way the stack (and recursion) works.

Answer (score 0):

when a method if invoked it needs space to keep its parameters, its local variables and the return adress  this space is called activation record (stack frame).

Recursion is calling a method that happens to have the same name as the caller,
therefore **a recursive call is not litterally a method calling it self but an instantiation of a method calling
another instantiation of the same original**. these invocations are represented internally by different activation records 
which means that they are differentiated by the system.