# QuickSort modified implementation to use Insertion Sort for short subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement quickSort that uses Insertion sort for subarrays that are shorter than a certain length. I have written this code but the problem is it works for records upto 400,000 integers but i need to make it run for 5000,000 Integer array. Its giving me hard time to find why am I getting the StackOverflow error for this.

```
public int[] quickSort2(int[] arrayOfIntegers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex < endIndex) {
        if (endIndex - startIndex < INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD) {
            InsertionSort(arrayOfIntegers, startIndex, endIndex);
        } else {
            int pivotIndex = partition2(arrayOfIntegers, startIndex, endIndex);
            quickSort2(arrayOfIntegers, startIndex, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort2(arrayOfIntegers, pivotIndex + 1, endIndex);
        }
    }
    return arrayOfIntegers;
}
```

Insertion Sort looks like this :

```
public int[] InsertionSort(int[] arrayOfNumbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        int key = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        int pointer = i - 1;
        while (pointer >= startIndex && arrayOfNumbers[pointer] > key) {
            arrayOfNumbers[pointer + 1] = arrayOfNumbers[pointer];
            pointer -= 1;
        }
        arrayOfNumbers[pointer + 1] = key;
    }
    return arrayOfNumbers;
}
```

QuickSort partition is :

```
private int partition2(int[] arrayOfIntegers, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = arrayOfIntegers[end];
    int pointer = start - 1;
    for (int i = start; i <= end - 1; i++) {
        if (arrayOfIntegers[i] <= pivot) {
            pointer += 1;
            int temporaryStorage = arrayOfIntegers[i];
            arrayOfIntegers[i] = arrayOfIntegers[pointer];
            arrayOfIntegers[pointer] = temporaryStorage;
        }
    }
    arrayOfIntegers[end] = arrayOfIntegers[pointer + 1];
    arrayOfIntegers[pointer + 1] = pivot;
    return (pointer + 1);
}
```

Also when i code to run QuickSort on array of size 5000,000 integers and using subarrays of length 3, 6, 9 etc to sort the entire array, it doesn't give me "StackOverflow" error.
Can someone please help

Comment: What does this mean? - `"using subarrays of length 3, 6, 9"`. Using these sizes where?

Comment: Pretty much duplicate - [Why does this quick sort cause stack overflow on nearly sorted lists and sorted lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20255628)

Answer (score 0):

You properly get a Stackoverflow because your implementation uses recursion. You call `quickSort2` out of your `quickSort2` method which will increase the stack on every call. Since the stack cannot grow endless you get an Stackoverflow.

If you increase your threshold to 3, 6, 9 (and so on) you will get significant less recursions (calls of `quickSort2`). That's why you don't get an Stackoverflow in this cases. But its only a matter of the size of your array. If it is large enough you will get a Stackoverflow anyway.

The solution is to eliminate the recursion from your code. Eliminating recursion will not only avoid a Stackoverflow, it will also increase the speed of your code since recursion is much slower compared to iterations (in Java).

For more see e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/ or Google `iterative quicksort`.