# Does java support and optimize away tail-recursive calls?

Tags: java, scala, optimization, recursion, jvm

Say I got a recursive function that is *tail recursive*. I wonder if this function will be implemented as recursion, growing on the stack, or will it be changed to a loop (since it is a tail-recursive function)?

I have just read that Scala detects such calls and optimizes it but is this a Scala-only thing or JVM in general?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this function is NOT tail-recursive. After nested call to sum(), there is still need to add something to the return value of that call.

Comment: That's *not* a tail call.

Comment: Regardless, HotSpot does not support TCO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3616483/139010

Comment: Why dont you do `new Throwable().printStackTrace();` at that begining of your method, and tell us what you see!

Comment: Creating a subList object is more expensive than the recursion (assuming you done run out of stack)  Of course the most efficient option is plain iteration.

Comment: Given that you are interested in this style of programming, is there a reason why you can't just use Scala?  The equivalent of the above (the whole thing) would be `println((0 to 5).sum)`.  If you consider using the sum() method cheating, you could generate the sum using a fold: `(0 /: (0 to 5))(_+_)`. As a method, a somewhat more general version of the above is `def sum( xs:Seq[Int] ):Int = if (xs.isEmpty) 0 else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)`.  Or you could write a tail-recursive version and it would actually get optimized (by scalac).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Java supports tail-recursive calls, but AFAIK it doesn't optimize them away. I think it's the Scala compiler that is simply capable of this, not the JVM itself. Check out the `@tailrec` annotation in Scala to see what more the compiler is capable of :)

But regardless of whether Java/JVM optimizes tail-recursion away, your function would be harder to optimize than necessary.

Look at this:

```
int sum(List<Integer> integers) {
    return sum(integers, 0);
}

int sum(List<Integer> integers, int sumSoFar) {
    if (integers.isEmpty())
        return sumSoFar;
    else
        return sum(
                integers.subList(1, integers.size()),
                sumSoFar + integers.get(0)
        );
}
```

See, I've added an overloaded `sum` with a so-far calculated sum parameter. This way when you recur in the `else` branch you don't need the actual stack frame any more - you got all you need as function arguments in the recursive call.

In your snippet the stack frame would probably have to exist as long as the recursive call..

Comment: you probably know this, but anyways, `@tailrec` is used only to **enforce** optimized code -- if compiler is not able to do so, it will throw compilation error. But still, code will be optimized if it is possible to do, whether such annotation is presented or not.

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes, good that you pointed out this here. `@tailrec`  in Scala is similar to `@Override` in Java (in terms of presence and compiler actions).

Comment: I believe this is called "Co-recursion"

Answer (score 10):

**Java and the JVM do not currently support tail calls**

The fundamental work that needs to happen is at the level of the JVM, not Java. There has been a slow moving line of work to address this (initially as part of [MLVM](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/subprojects.html#TailCall) now under [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main)). Despite being relatively old, this [2007 blog from John Rose](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/tail-calls-in-the-vm) is a good and short overview of how the JVM bytecode could be altered. I think that the tail call work was pushed aside in favor of finishing `invokedynamic` first (and that has uncovered [more tricky design considerations for tail calls](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/tailcalls-meet-invokedynamic)). Here is an excerpt from [the latest Project Loom proposal](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html):

> As adding the ability to manipulate call stacks to the JVM will undoubtedly be required, it is also the goal of this project to add an even lighter-weight construct that will allow unwinding the stack to some point and then invoke a method with given arguments (basically, a generalization of efficient tail-calls). We will call that feature unwind-and-invoke, or UAI.

---

Some other details:

- Java as a language is unlikely to ever *automatically* optimize tail-calls. This is because most implementations of tail-call elimination have somewhat unintuitive effects on the callstack (eg. if you throw an exception in a recursive call, you won't see all of the recursive calls in the stack trace).

  JavaScript is an example of a language that tried to automatically optimize tail-calls (in ES2015), and [here is a debrief from the V8 team](https://v8.dev/blog/modern-javascript#proper-tail-calls) explaining the difficulties. They've since removed the feature and have switched to backing a proposal [that supports tail-call optimization only when it is explicit](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-ptc-syntax).

  If the JVM ever adds support for tail-calls at the bytecode level, I speculate Java might also support explicit tail-call optimization (ie. in the form of an annotation on a `return` or an annotation on a function or maybe even a new keyword).
- Scala tries to detect and optimize tail recursion into JVM bytecode loops. [Here is a project](https://github.com/Sipkab/jvm-tail-recursion) that promises to perform this sort of optimization on existing JVM bytecode. The idea has not been adopted by Java because it is somewhat brittle and limited:

  1. mutually recursive functions get really tricky (Scala's `@tailrec` just gives up)
  2. polymorphic recursion can't work
  3. generalized tail calls obviously can't work

Comment: Its not clear how up to date some of the pages you link to are.

Comment: @Raedwald I spent a while researching this in the process of trying to figure out how to best compile WASM tail calls on the JVM. AFAICT, there really isn't anything much yet. Even the actual WIP is still pretty bare: https://github.com/openjdk/loom. Unlike other prioritized projects like Amber and Valhalla, Loom doesn't yet have a docs repo to talk about the design. It also doesn't have any draft JEPs: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0. I would be quite happy to see another answer proving me wrong though.

Comment: Scala's [`@tailrec` annotation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) is a demand to the compiler that a function be optimized. It is not limited to doing so on only functions marked with that annotation. Scala is more than happy to go hunting for any `final` functions which can exhibit TCO.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks for the reference! I had no idea this was the case. Do you know if there's a way to tell the Scala compiler to _not_ perform TCO?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to suppress it. There could be some obscure annotation or compiler setting I'm not aware of, though

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Apparently there is `-g:notailcalls`, but I don't see a way to disable on a per function basis.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044) from April 2014:

> It's important to note that this isn't a bug in the JVM. It's an optimization that can be implemented to help functional programmers who use recursion, which is much more common and normal in those languages. I recently spoke to Brian Goetz at Oracle about this optimization, and he said that it's on a list of things to be added to the JVM, but it's just not a high-priority item.

Answer (score -3):

Tail recursion of Factorial in java, it has space complexity of O(1)

```
  int tailFactorial(int x){
    return tailFactorial(x, 1);
}

int tailFactorial(int x, int totalFactor){
    if(x == 0){
        return totalFactor;
    }else{
        return tailFactorial(x-1, totalFactor * x);
    }

}
```