# I wrote this code to solve towers of hanoi. after 32453 iterations my code stops working

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class towers{
  public static void  main(String args[])
  {
       honoi('A','B','C',(long)1,n);
   }
  static int disk_no(long i,int n) // to find the next disk to move
   {
       if(i%2!=0)
           return 1;
       else
      {
          int j;
       long k;
       for(j=2;j<=n;j++)
             for(k=0;k<Math.pow(2,n-j);k++)
                  if(i==(long)Math.pow(2,(long)j-1)*((2*k)+1))
                  {
                     System.out.println("returning :"+j);
                     return j;
                  }
         return 0;
      }
      }
      static void honoi(char x,char y,char z,long i,int n)
      {
          if(i<Math.pow(2,n))
          {
             switch((int)i%2)
              {
                 case 0:System.out.println("STEP "+i+" :\tMove disk "+(long)disk_no(i,n)+" from pole "+z+" to "+y);
                             honoi(x,y,z,++i,n);break;
               default:System.out.println("STEP "+i+" :\tMove disk "+(long)disk_no(i,n)+" from pole "+x+" to "+y);
                              honoi(y,z,x,++i,n);
              }
           }
       }}
```

I read n value from user as number of disks ofcourse I skipped it here
I thought that the problem is with 
    disk_no() 
function if not mention the logical errors in the code if any

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Try explaining the problem in details. For instance, After 32453 iterations what are the values of the local vars ? etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code throws a StackOverflowError.

Essentially, your `honoi` method prints out all the moves necessary to solve the Towers of Hanoi puzzle with `n` disks from step `i` onwards.  It does this by figuring out what is necessary for move `i` and then calling itself with `i` replaced with `i + 1` and optionally with `x`, `y` and `z` switched around.

The problem arises because your method calls itself.  Each time Java calls your `honoi` method, it needs to store where to return to when executing the method finishes.   It stores these return locations on a 'stack'.  When a method returns, Java removes the last of these locations from the top of the stack and resumes running your program from this location.  There is only a limited amount of space for the 'stack' used for these return locations.  If this stack grows too large, Java will throw a StackOverflowError.

If you run your program with a large number of disks, your code will require too much space to store return locations, because your method calls itself too many times before it returns.  Your `honoi` method only returns once all of the moves have been displayed.

To avoid the stack overflow, I modified your `honoi` method to the following, which uses a loop instead of calling itself.  `i` is now a loop variable, so I've removed `i` as a method parameter.  You will need to remove the `(long)1` from your call to `honoi` in `main()`:

```
  static void honoi(char x,char y,char z,int n)
  {
      for (long i = 1; i < Math.pow(2,n); ++i)
      {
         switch((int)i%2)
          {
             case 0:System.out.println("STEP "+i+" :\tMove disk "+(long)disk_no(i,n)+" from pole "+z+" to "+y);
                 break;
             default:System.out.println("STEP "+i+" :\tMove disk "+(long)disk_no(i,n)+" from pole "+x+" to "+y);
                 char temp = x;
                 x = y;
                 y = z;
                 z = temp;
          }
      }
  }
```

The four lines from `char temp = x;` onwards swap around `x`, `y`, and `z`, as your recursive version of this method called itself with the `x`, `y` and `z` arguments switched around in the `default` case.

---

I don't know if you originally wrote this program in another language (e.g. a functional language such as Haskell) which supports *tail recursion optimization*.  If a language supports this optimization, then it will be able to detect whether a method ends with a call to the same method, and if so, jump back to the start of the method using a kind of 'goto'.  Your code would seem to benefit from this kind of optimization: if tail recursion optimization was supported in Java, your code would quite possibly run without an error. However, [that's not likely to happen in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616483/why-does-the-jvm-still-not-support-tail-call-optimization).