# How to increase the Java stack size?

Tags: java, stack, stack-overflow

I asked this question to get to know how to increase the runtime call stack size in the JVM. I've got an answer to this, and I've also got many useful answers and comments relevant to how Java handles the situation where a large runtime stack is needed. I've extended my question with the summary of the responses.

Originally I wanted to increase the JVM stack size so programs like runs without a `StackOverflowError`.

```
public class TT {
  public static long fact(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fact(1 << 15));
  }
}
```

The corresponding configuration setting is the `java -Xss...` command-line flag with a large enough value. For the program `TT` above, it works like this with OpenJDK's JVM:

```
$ javac TT.java
$ java -Xss4m TT
```

One of the answers has also pointed out that the `-X...` flags are implementation dependent. I was using

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.1) (6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1~8.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

It is also possible to specify a large stack only for one thread (see in one of the answers how). This is recommended over `java -Xss...` to avoid wasting memory for threads that don't need it.

I was curious how large a stack the program above exactly needs, so I've run it `n` increased:

- -Xss4m can be enough for `fact(1 << 15)`
- -Xss5m can be enough for `fact(1 << 17)`
- -Xss7m can be enough for `fact(1 << 18)`
- -Xss9m can be enough for `fact(1 << 19)`
- -Xss18m can be enough for `fact(1 << 20)`
- -Xss35m can be enough for `fact(1 << 21)`
- -Xss68m can be enough for `fact(1 << 22)`
- -Xss129m can be enough for `fact(1 << 23)`
- -Xss258m can be enough for `fact(1 << 24)`
- -Xss515m can be enough for `fact(1 << 25)`

From the numbers above it seems that Java is using about 16 bytes per stack frame for the function above, which is reasonable.

The enumeration above contains *can be enough* instead of *is enough*, because the stack requirement is not deterministic: running it multiple times with the same source file and the same `-Xss...` sometimes succeeds and sometimes yields a `StackOverflowError`. E.g. for 1 << 20, `-Xss18m` was enough in 7 runs out of 10, and `-Xss19m` wasn't always enough either, but `-Xss20m` was enough (in all 100 runs out of 100). Does garbage collection, the JIT kicking in, or something else cause this nondeterministic behavior?

The stack trace printed at a `StackOverflowError` (and possibly at other exceptions as well) shows only the most recent 1024 elements of the runtime stack. An answer below demonstrates how to count the exact depth reached (which might be a lot larger than 1024).

Many people who responded has pointed out that it is a good and safe coding practice to consider alternative, less stack-hungry implementations of the same algorithm. In general, it is possible to convert to a set of recursive functions to iterative functions (using a e.g. `Stack` object, which gets populated on the heap instead of on the runtime stack). For this particular `fact` function, it is quite easy to convert it. My iterative version would look like:

```
public class TTIterative {
  public static long fact(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    if (n > 65) return 0;  // Enough powers of 2 in the product to make it (long)0.
    long f = 2;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
      f *= i;
    }
    return f;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fact(1 << 15));
  }
}
```

FYI, as the iterative solution above shows it, the `fact` function cannot compute the exact factorial of numbers above 65 (actually, even above 20), because the Java built-in type `long` would overflow. Refactoring `fact` so it would return a `BigInteger` instead of `long` would yield exact results for large inputs as well.

Comment: Looks more simple than it is. fact() is called 32K times recursively. That should be less than 1MB of stack. :-/

Comment: @Aaron: + Function overhead, which is.. a LOT

Comment: Aside from your stack issues. note that you are blowing up your long and ints. 1<<4 is the max value I can use before going negative and then into 0. Try using BigInteger

Comment: Not sure that the function overhead is actually thaaat much though-- I think you should still be able to make 2^15 calls in the order of a few megabytes of stack space.

Comment: @gameaddict: I don't care about BigInteger, see this paragraph in the original question: I know that that my program prints the result modulo 2^64 (2 complement), that's fine.

Comment: Note: You are setting the stack size of every thread and producing a meaningless result, all to avoid refactoring one line of code. I am glad you have your priorities sorted out. :P

Comment: important note: Programs can run without `StackOverFlow`, programmers not.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Hmm... it works for me and with far less than 999MB of stack:

```
> java -Xss4m Test
0
```

(Windows JDK 7, build 17.0-b05 client VM, and Linux JDK 6 - same version information as you posted)

Comment: Thanks to this question and your answer, i managed to complete my assigment. My DFS function had to recurse on a graph with ~10^5 vertices. Finally it worked with -Xss129m :D

Answer (score 13):

I assume you calculated the "depth of 1024" by the recurring lines in the stack trace?

Obviously, the stack trace array length in Throwable seems to be limited to 1024.
Try the following program:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println(fact(1 << 15));
        }
        catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.err.println("true recursion level was " + level);
            System.err.println("reported recursion level was " +
                               e.getStackTrace().length);
        }
    }

    private static int level = 0;
    public static long fact(int n) {
        level++;
        return n < 2 ? n : n * fact(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to play with the thread stack size, you'll want to look at the -Xss option on the Hotspot JVM.  It may be something different on non Hotspot VM's since the -X parameters to the JVM are distribution specific, IIRC.

On Hotspot, this looks like `java -Xss16M` if you want to make the size 16 megs.

Type `java -X -help` if you want to see all of the distribution specific JVM parameters you can pass in.  I am not sure if this works the same on other JVMs, but it prints all of Hotspot specific parameters.

For what it's worth - I would recommend limiting your use of recursive methods in Java.  It's not too great at optimizing them - for one the JVM doesn't support tail recursion (see [Does the JVM prevent tail call optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations)).  Try refactoring your factorial code above to use a while loop instead of recursive method calls.

Answer (score 9):

The only way to control the size of stack within process is start a new `Thread`. But you can also control by creating a self-calling sub Java process with the `-Xss` parameter.

```
public class TT {
    private static int level = 0;

    public static long fact(int n) {
        level++;
        return n < 2 ? n : n * fact(n - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(null, null, "TT", 1000000) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    level = 0;
                    System.out.println(fact(1 << 15));
                } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
                    System.err.println("true recursion level was " + level);
                    System.err.println("reported recursion level was "
                            + e.getStackTrace().length);
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
        t.join();
        try {
            level = 0;
            System.out.println(fact(1 << 15));
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.err.println("true recursion level was " + level);
            System.err.println("reported recursion level was "
                    + e.getStackTrace().length);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer, it's nice to know about options in addition to `java -Xss...` .

Comment: I got excited about this, but then having read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread - the stacksize constructor - the excitement went away.

Comment: I wonder which platforms are they when the document only say - "On some platforms"

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to give a sensible solution since you are keen to avoid all sane approaches. Refactoring one line of code is the senible solution.

Note: Using -Xss sets the stack size of every thread and is a very bad idea.

Another approach is byte code manipulation to change the code as follows;

```
public static long fact(int n) { 
    return n < 2 ? n : n > 127 ? 0 : n * fact(n - 1); 
}
```

given every answer for n > 127 is 0. This avoid changing the source code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that setting a high stack size would waste memory for threads that don't need it. Also thanks for pointing out that the `fact` function in the question can be refactored to use much less stack space.

Comment: @pts, your thanks are noted. I think this is a sensible question given a much more complex use case, but those are very rare.

Answer (score 4):

Add this option

```
--driver-java-options -Xss512m
```

to your spark-submit command will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did [Anagram excersize](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/assignment/view?assignment_id=17), which is like [Count Change](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node16.html) problem but with 50 000 denominations (coins). I am [not sure that it can be done iteratively](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SicpIterationExercise), I do not care. I just know that the -xss option had no effect -- I always failed after 1024 stack frames (might be scala does bad job delivering to to java or printStackTrace limitation. I do not know). This is bad option, as explained anyway. You do not want all threads in to app to be monstrous. However, I did some experiments with new Thread (stack size). This works indeed,

```
  def measureStackDepth(ss: Long): Long = {
    var depth: Long = 0
      val thread: Thread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
        override def run() {
          try {
          def sum(n: Long): Long = {depth += 1; if (n== 0) 0 else sum(n-1) + 1}
          println("fact = " + sum(ss * 10))
          } catch {
            case e: StackOverflowError => // eat the exception, that is expected
          }
        }
      }, "deep stack for money exchange", ss)
      thread.start()
      thread.join()
    depth
  }                                               //> measureStackDepth: (ss: Long)Long


  for (ss <- (0 to 10)) println("ss = 10^" +  ss + " allows stack of size " -> measureStackDepth((scala.math.pow (10, ss)).toLong) )
                                                  //> fact = 10
                                                  //| (ss = 10^0 allows stack of size ,11)
                                                  //| fact = 100
                                                  //| (ss = 10^1 allows stack of size ,101)
                                                  //| fact = 1000
                                                  //| (ss = 10^2 allows stack of size ,1001)
                                                  //| fact = 10000
                                                  //| (ss = 10^3 allows stack of size ,10001)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^4 allows stack of size ,1336)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^5 allows stack of size ,5456)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^6 allows stack of size ,62736)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^7 allows stack of size ,623876)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^8 allows stack of size ,6247732)
                                                  //| (ss = 10^9 allows stack of size ,62498160)
```

You see that stack can grow exponentially deeper with exponentially more stack alloted to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Weird! You are saying that you want to generate a **recursion of 1<<15 depth**???!!!!

I'd suggest DON'T try it. The size of the stack will be `2^15 * sizeof(stack-frame)`. I don't know what stack-frame size is, but 2^15 is 32.768. Pretty much... Well, if it stops at 1024 (2^10) you'll have to make it 2^5 times bigger, it is, 32 times bigger than with your actual setting.

Answer (score 0):

Other posters have pointed out how to increase memory and that you could memoize calls. I'd suggest that for many applications, you can use Stirling's formula to approximate large n! very quickly with almost no memory footprint.

Take a gander at this post, which has some analysis of the function and code:

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/stirlings-approximation-formula-clojure/