# Stack Overflow error occurs when using recursive fibonacci function

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Here's my code and it runs well with values of 400 to 4000 but once it's about 4mil, I get stack overflow errors.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Fib {
static int c=1,b=2;
static long sum1=0,sum2=0;

static long fib(long a){
if(a==1){
    return 1;
}
if(a==2){
    return 2;
}
else{
    return fib(a-1)+fib(a-2);
}

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
sum2= fib(4000000);
    System.out.println("Sum %f" +sum2);
}
    }
```

Comment: What's the question? You know your machine has finite resources, right?

Comment: Recursive Functions run on stack and the stack is not endless.

Comment: Your getting a stack overflow error because your stack has overfloweth.

Comment: ...because the difference in resources needed when calculating for 4.000 and 4.000.000 is so small.

Comment: As an aside, declaring sum1 sum2 b and c as class variables seems unnecessary.

Comment: Recursive functions can be great for clarity but be careful how deep the recursion is.  Yes, you have run out of stack space and this is why!

Comment: Four million is a _completely_ unreasonable input; the growth of Fib is explosive.  The four millionth item alone has almost a million digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - you're running out of stack space. It's far from infinite, and you're using it up on each recursive call. You're trying to end up with a stack with 4 million stack frames - that's not going to work.

I suggest you consider an iterative approach. Even if you had an infinite amount of stack, that code would probably not complete before the heat death of the universe. (Think about the complexity of this code...)

Comment: Integer goes from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so you could just use `int` instead of `float`

Comment: @PRamesh: There's no need to use `long` here for the parameter, as 4 million is well within the bounds of an int. However, the *result* of fib(4000000) certainly won't fit in a long. You'll get a result, but it will have wrapped around many times, as adding two large numbers will end up giving a negative number...

Comment: Nothing wrong with `long` unless you're getting arithmetic overflow errors.  Though you don't need to declare it in the class.

Comment: @SideshowBob: You wouldn't get arithmetic overflow errors from adding longs together... it will overflow, but it won't be an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the stack size of Java programs. Example:

```
java -Xss4m YourProgram
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size)

Nevertheless I would also recommend an iterative method.

Comment: That's assuming a single byte per stack frame. I suspect that's not going to do the job...

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet above mentioned, your code would require a huge amount of time to run - 2 to the 4 million, which is not practical in any way. Frankly i'm surprised the stack ran dry at all, I'd think the code would just run for a ridiculous amount of time.

You should use an iterative approach. Here's a nicer implementation of the fibonacci sequence:

```
static long fib(long i){
    if ( i == 0 || i == 1 ) return 1;
    long a = 1; //This is the 0th element 
    long b = 1; //This is the 1st element
    while( i-- > 1 ){ //Each iteration, sets a and b to the next element in the fibonacci sequence
        long temp = b;
        a += b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    return b;
}
```