# StackOverFlow Error while handling input of size 100000 and more

Tags: java, collections, stack-overflow

I am using Collections.sort()in a List of size 100000 and getting StackOverFlow error. How can I scale this up? Here is the code:

This is a part of a big project. Collections.sort() is being called iteratively over the list as follows: The list size decreases at each step and the process iterates until the size of the list becomes 1.

```
public static Node buildTree(int d,  List<kdtrees.DataPoint> list) 
{
   if(list.isEmpty())
   {   
       return null;
   }

   else if(list.size() == 1) // S is singleton, return leaf
   {  
       System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1).text);
       Node t = new Node(0,0,null,null,list.get(list.size() - 1));

       return t;
   }

   else
   {           


      Collections.sort(list, compByX);
       double m = findMedian(d, list);


       List<kdtrees.DataPoint> left = new ArrayList<kdtrees.DataPoint>();
       List<kdtrees.DataPoint> right = new ArrayList<kdtrees.DataPoint>();

       for(DataPoint i: list)
       {
           if(i.Xvalue < m) 
           {
             left.add(i);
           }
           else
           {
             right.add(i);
           }


       }


        Node t = new Node(d, m, buildTree((d+1)%3,left)buildTree((d+1)%3,right), null);

        return t ;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase to Java stack size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size)

Comment: Collections.sort() should have no trouble with a list of 100000 items. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere? Can you post a complete example?

Comment: This is a part of a big project. Collections.sort() is being called iteratively over the list as follows: The list size decreases at each step and the process iterates until the size of the list becomes 1.:

Comment: @LouisWasserman is right. Take the case where the input list has 3 identical items - none is less than the median, so your left side will be empty and your right side the same as the input list.

Comment: Thanks. I will handle this corner case and get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem isn't in `Collections.sort`, it's that you're missing a scenario in which the list size *doesn't* decrease at each step.  (Specifically: what happens if all the elements of the list are equal?)

The stack overflow is caused by your code, not `Collections.sort`.

Comment: A good example of **"select" isn't broken** from http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the stack size in VM arguments using -Xss option.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort()` according to javadocs uses `a modified mergesort` (which is a recursive algorithm). On each iteration of this algorithm a recursive call is made which increases stack size.

You have to increase the stack size with `-Xss` option or redesign your program to make it work.

Comment: Even if Collections.sort is implemented recursively, it's going to be O(log(n)) in stack size - not enough to blow the stack on 100000 items.

Comment: @Alex Probably you're right. 100K is not such a big collection to cause `SOE`.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase stack size

> java -Xss4m Program