# Eclipse Error with Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse

I have springtool suite kepler (v3.3) running on ubuntu 12.04 and java 7. Now I have an error since update java 1.7.0_40.

```
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

sts.ini

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Also I use vmwarevfabric server 2.9 (incluided in sts)

can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's Eclipse/STS giving the error, try putting

```
-Xss4m
```

to the end of the file (or at least after `-vmargs`).

See [How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size) for more.

Comment: Finally I changed arguments in vmware configuration and it worked. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Being tracked by https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-3578

Answer from there:

> Workaround: find the tc server launhc configuration via the "Run >> Run Configurations ..." menu. Change the vm commandline option to increase the stacksize. I.e something like:
>   -Xss256k