# VMWare : The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tools Suit 3.2.0.RELEASE.When I try to start the `VMware server`, I get the following error

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
```

I searched in Google. [Got this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772651/2353403).

I changed the **STS.ini** to following

```
-clean
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xss8m
```

And I restarted STS, and OS also. But still I am getting same error. Is there anywhere else I need to change?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Error with Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772373/eclipse-error-with-java-7)

Being tracked by https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-3578

Answer from there:

> Workaround: find the tc server launhc configuration via the "Run >> Run Configurations ..." menu. Change the vm commandline option to increase the stacksize. I.e something like:
> -Xss256k