# Knights Tour Java

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, knights-tour

I am receiving a StackOverflow error when ever I run the program instead of finding the Knights Tour. Any idea what is causing this and how I can change my code around to actually find the Knights Tour and get rid of this error. Project is for my CS280 class and is due on Friday please help. Thanks!!

```
public class KnightsTourDriver {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        KnightsTour tour1 = new KnightsTour;
        tour1.findTour(1);
        tour1.displayTour();
    }
}  



import java.util.Arrays;
class KnightsTour
{

    static int the_board[][] = new int[8][8];
    int the_tour[][] = new int [8][8];
    int k,moves = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0; 
    int z, j = 1;
    boolean tour_found, isSafe;

        //fills 2D array with 0's
        public KnightsTour()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
                {
                 for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) 
                    {
                            the_board[i][r] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
        /*recursive method, checks how many moves were made if 16 were made tour finished, 
        else if not moves knight checks if the move is valid if not back tracks*/
        public void findTour(int q)
        {

            if(moves == 64)
                {
                    tour_found = true;
                }

            else 
                move(q); 

            if(isSafe == true)
                    {
                        findTour(q++);
                        moves++;
                    }
            else
                if(isSafe == false)
                    {
                        findTour(q*(-1));
                        moves--;
                    }
        }
        //used to keep prevent arrayindexoutofbounds error
        public boolean arrayInBounds(int x, int y)
        { 
        if(x < 8 && y < 8 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            else return false;
        }
        /*move method uses switch statement to decide which move the knight should make
        based on a case number, negative case numbers back track knight. if statement checks
        if the current array element is empty and the index is inbounds*/
        public void move(int a)
        {

            switch (a)
            {
               case 1:
                if(arrayInBounds(x+2, y+1) == true){
                   if(the_board[x+2][y+1] != 0){                          
                        the_board[x+2][y+1]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                    }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 2:
                if (arrayInBounds(x+1, y+2) == true){
                    if(the_board[x+1][y+2] != 0){               
                            the_board[x+1][y+2]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 3:
                 if(arrayInBounds(x-1, y+2) == true){
                   if(the_board[x-1][y+2] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-1][y+2]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                 }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 4:
                if (arrayInBounds(x-2, y+1) == true){
                    if(the_board[x-2][y+1] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-2][y+1]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 5:
                if(arrayInBounds(x-2, y-1) == true){
                    if(the_board[x-2][y-1] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-2][y-1]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 6:
                if(arrayInBounds(x-1, y-2) == true){
                        if(the_board[x-1][y-2] != 0){                    
                            the_board[x-1][y-2]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
            }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 7:
                 if(arrayInBounds(x+1, y-2) == true){
                    if(the_board[x+1][y-2] != 0){          
                            the_board[x+1][y-2]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                 }
                 else isSafe = false;
               case 8:
                if(arrayInBounds(x+2, y-1) == true){
                 if(the_board[x+2][y-1] != 0){
                            the_board[x+2][y-1]=j;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else isSafe = false;
                        break;
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case -1:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                    case -2:
                        j--;
                        tryNextMove(a);
                        break;
                    case -3:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                    case -4:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                  case -5:
                     j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                    case -6:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                    case -7:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
                   case -8:
                      j--;
                      tryNextMove(a);
                      break;
             }
        }
        public void tryNextMove(int m)
        {
            move(m++);
        }
        //for loop to display tour once found//         
        public void displayTour()
        {
            int v = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
                {
                 for (int e = 0; e < 8; e++) 
                    {               
                                if(v % 8 == 0)
                                {
                                    System.out.print(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                } 
                        else    
                            System.out.print(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                            v++;                
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace would be nice but if you debug it yourself, that would let you lean a lot more than any answer that we can provide.

Comment: Take a look at the first set of `if` conditions in your `findTour` method; is there ever a pathway that **doesn't** recursively call `findTour` again?

Comment: Please learn about the postincrement and the preincrement operators. Maybe you then see your mistake.

Comment: do you mind puttin in a main method that would kick it all off? so some1 readng can quickly play w/ code

Comment: how do I show the stack trace?

Comment: easiest way to figure out what is wrong is to put a System.out.println at the start of findTour and one at the start of move, writing out the values for all of the variables used in that function

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm really requires a large depth of recursive calls, you can pass an argument to the JVM on startup to increase the limit for the stack size :   [-Xss4m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size)

Of course, this will only delay the problem if your algorithm recurses without limit.

Answer (score 0):

You need some breaks in your case statements in the switch, otherwise it'll fall through.

Comment: I implemented the break statements and still getting this error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at KnightsTour.tryNextMove(KnightsTour.java:189)
at KnightsTour.move(KnightsTour.java:155)

---jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: The breaks in cases with if/elses don't look correct to me. And you need to include line numbers so that we can see where line 189 is.

Comment: KnightsTour tour1 = new KnightsTour; is wrong for a start!

Comment: Well I'm not going to debug it for you, but I ran it. It looks like it just never terminates. You need to think about the termination conditions, and why they are not being met.