# StackOverflowError: LinkedList & ArrayList deserialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist, linked-list

When deserializing (readObject) an LinkedList with approx. 300 elements, each of which contains another nested ArrayList with approx. 10-30 elements each, I sometimes get an StackOverflowError. The ObjectOutput/Input file has a size of 1MB. All this is done on Android.

I've already found some similar questions here, but none of them helped me to solve this. How can I face this issue? I've read one idea to iterate over the list and write each contained object itself to the ObjectOutputStream but then I've looked into ArrayList's writeObject method and figured out, that it is already done this way. So, how can I prevent the StackOverflowError?

Here the stack:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:114)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkReadPrimitiveTypes(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:539)
at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:147)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readLong(ObjectInputStream.java:1400)
at java.util.Date.readObject(Date.java:799)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:984)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1023)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
at org.felikz.app.WebserviceApplication.reloadAppState(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: if you use Android Studio - start application and look to Memory Monitor. May be it more than 1mb. And about stackoverflow - it has been caused when you have very many fuction calls, may be you call you function recursively?

Comment: I already know the problem and its cause. I'm looking for a way to solve this.

Comment: Is this happening in the emulator or on the actual device?

Comment: On multiple devices, e.g. Galaxy S5, S4, and many others.

Comment: Can you set the jvm args?  If so, then -Xss1m should fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the provided stack trace, you have nested `ArrayList`s eleven levels deep.

```
LinkedList
└ ArrayList
  └ ArrayList
    └ ArrayList
      └ ArrayList
        └ ArrayList
          └ ArrayList
            └ ArrayList
              └ ArrayList
                └ ArrayList
                  └ ArrayList
                    └ ArrayList
                      └ Date
```

> So, how can I prevent the StackOverflowError?

To prevent stack overflow, flatten out your data structure.

Or if that is not feasible, check out [How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size).

Comment: Okay that's really strange. What's also strange is that the serialization (writeObject) always works, but readObject does not.. Shouldn't that problem also occur on writeObject?

Comment: That's a good point - perhaps `writeObject()` travels a shallower series of methods, or methods with less parameters, thus incurs less overhead on the stack.