# Stackoverflow exception caused by recursive call of partitionStep in QuickSort

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I try to implement quicksort algorithm for `int[]`. I coded the partition step correctly but then I wanted to call partition step method recursively to get the array sorted, unfortunately I pass wrong indexes to the recursive call and I get StackOverflow exception.

I based it on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_G9BkAm6B8

```
public class Quicksort {

    public static void partition(int[] t, int i, int j) {

        int start = i, end = j;
        int pivot = t[(i + j) / 2]; // select the pivot as the middle value
        System.out.println("pivot: " + pivot);
        int temp;
        while (i < j) {
            while (t[i] < pivot) { // looking for value greater or equal to the
                                    // pivot
                i++;
            }
            while (t[j] > pivot) { // looking for value lower or equal to the
                                    // pivot
                j--;
            }
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " j = " + j + " swaps " + t[i] + " with " + t[j]);
            temp = t[i]; // swap
            t[i] = t[j];
            t[j] = temp;
            i++; // move to the next element
            j--; // move to the prev element
            display(t);
        }
        // I CALL THEM WRONG
        partition(t, start, j); // partition for the left part of the array
        partition(t, i, end); // partiion for the right part of the array
    }

    public static void display(int[] t) {
        for (int el : t)
            System.out.print(el + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] t = { 6, 4, 1, 32, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 1 };
        display(t);
        partition(t, 0, t.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that your recursion has no exit condition.  You don't have a single return statement in your `partition` method.  When your while loop exits, it will just make additional call into the `partition` method again.  But there's nothing in the code to say, "stop making recursive calls into partition". Hence, the stack overflow.

I think you want to at least say this at the top of the partition function.  This should clear up the stack overflow.

```
public static void partition(int[] t, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= j)  {
        return;
    }
```

Also I'm not sure, but shouldn't this line:

```
partition(t, j, end); //partiion for the right part of the array
```

Really be this:

```
partition(t, i+1, end); //partiion for the right part of the array
```

Comment: `if (i >= j)  {
        return;
    }` and `partition(t, i, end);` did the job. The `i+1` was too much. I haven't had practice in this sort of things in a while. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the if statement to check whether `i` is less than or equal to `j` after the while...

```
public class QuickSort {

public static void display(int[] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println( arr[i] );

    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int[] data = new int[]{ 5, 10, 1, 9, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 6,7 };
    System.out.println("Unsorted array : " );
    display( data );
    quickSort( data, 0, data.length - 1 );
    System.out.println( "Sorted array: " );
    display( data );
}

public static void quickSort( int[] arr, int left, int right ) {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int temp;
    int pivot = arr[( left + right ) / 2];
    while( i <= j ) {
        while( arr[i] < pivot ) {
            i++;
        }
        while( arr[j] > pivot ) {
            j--;
        }
        // You forgot to test here...
        if( i <= j ) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if( left < j ) {
        quickSort( arr, left, j );
    }
    if( i < right ) {
        quickSort( arr, i, right );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are doing deep recursive calls you may want to look into enlarging the stack size using the -Xss argument. You can find a full answer here: [How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size)

I know that your code is problematic and not the actual size of the stack but this may prove useful once you've fixed the code.