# What sets the stack size?

Tags: java, jvm

I have written the code to get the size of the stack of my computer.

```
public class TestStack {

  private static int c;

  public static void main(String... args){
    try{
      f();
    } catch (StackOverflowError e){
      System.out.println(c);
    }
  }

  private static void f(){
    c ++;
    f();
  }
}
```

The result of its work is: 11908

What sets the size of the stack (JVM, OS or something else)? Is it possible to change the stack size?

Comment: Are you talking about the heap size in JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JVM and yes you can pass parms to change the stack size.  This question/answer is somewhat close to your question.  [How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size)