# Apache Camel timer route too long causing StackOverflow exception

Tags: java, apache-camel, stack-overflow

I have many data, which are transported using camel from destination A to destination B, until there is something in A.. That is causing stackoverflowException.
There is no recursion, just simply: 
Load Groups from source, save each group to target, load users for each group, save each user. Source and target are reached using Restlet component. Whole process is started each hour by timer component.

As a result is extremely long stacktrace (aprox 1000 lines). Solution is to increase stack size: [How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, which solved `StackOverFlowException` is to use `SEDA` component for places, which are repeatedly called - so for loading and saving users and groups, I used [Camel SEDA Component](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html).