# How to avoid StackOverflow Error in Recursive MazeSolver

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Like many other java students in college, I need to develop a maze program that solves the maze. My solveMaze method that implements recursion returned a stackoverflow runtime error. How do I solve this problem please? Does this have to do with my algorithm? Thanks in advance.

A) I created a solution maze that array that's going to hold the path to the exit.

B) Then, I implemented a method `solveMaze()` that took a step toward the exit everytime it's called.

Note: The `isWall()` method checks if the position you're moving to is a wall or not.

```java
  public void showPath() {
    int[][] sol = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
    for (int j = 0; j < sol.length; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < sol[0].length; i++) {
        sol[j][i] = m[j][i];
      }
    }
    if (solveMaze(sol, m.length - 1, 0, exitCords) == false)
      System.out.println("Solution doesn't exist");
    else {
      for (int y = 0; y < sol.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < sol[0].length; x++) {
          if (sol[y][x] == exitCords[0] && sol[y][x] == exitCords[1]) {
            System.out.print("E ");
          } else {
            if (sol[y][x] == 1) {
              System.out.print("  ");
            } else if (sol[y][x] == 3) {
              System.out.print("~");
            } else {
              System.out.print("# ");
            }
          }

        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean solveMaze(int[][] sol, int y, int x, int[] exitCords) {
    //exitCords[] is a one-dimensional array that holds the x and y coordinate of the exit point on a maze.
    if (y == exitCords[1] && x == exitCords[0]) {//Base Case
      return true;
    }
    //North
    if (!isWall(x, y - 1) && sol[y - 1][x] != 3) {
      sol[y][x] = 3;//3 is assigned to positions you already visited.
      y--;
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      //Implement recursion to call the solveMaze again on this line.
      solveMaze(sol, y, x, exitCords);
      return true;
    }

    //South
    else if (!isWall(x, y + 1) && sol[y + 1][x] != 3) {
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      y++;
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      solveMaze(sol, y, x, exitCords);
      return true;
    }
    //East
    else if (!isWall(x + 1, y) && sol[y][x + 1] != 3) {
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      x++;
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      solveMaze(sol, y, x, exitCords);
      return true;
    }
    //West
    else if (!isWall(x - 1, y) && sol[y][x - 1] != 3) {
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      x--;
      sol[y][x] = 3;
      solveMaze(sol, y, x, exitCords);
      return true;
    }
    /*The following line of code are to get out of dead ends and replace every position near a dead end with a wall*/
    else if ((isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x + 1, y)) || (isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x - 1, y))
        || (isWall(x - 1, y) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x + 1, y)) || (isWall(x - 1, y) && isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x + 1, y))) {

      if (isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x + 1, y)) {
        sol[y][x] = 0;
        solveMaze(sol, y, x - 1, exitCords);
        return true;
      }
      if (isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x - 1, y)) {
        sol[y][x] = 0;
        solveMaze(sol, y, x + 1, exitCords);
        return true;
      }
      if (isWall(x - 1, y) && isWall(x, y + 1) && isWall(x + 1, y)) {
        sol[y][x] = 0;
        solveMaze(sol, y - 1, x, exitCords);
        return true;
      }
      if (isWall(x - 1, y) && isWall(x, y - 1) && isWall(x + 1, y)) {
        sol[y][x] = 0;
        solveMaze(sol, y + 1, x, exitCords);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I understand you are learning, so i think you need to figure this one out on your own. But here is a tip for solving your problem: Clean, your, code. This way you can more eassily spot your problem and debug much faster. This link provides powerful knowledge about recursion, it's directed at Python, but still you can take a learning out of it, espacially the rules at the top: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/TheThreeLawsofRecursion.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make help possible and easier please post [mcve]. Include test data and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You have different ways to solve the problem:

- The first one is to rewrite your code without using recursion (no luck for tail recursion - [Java doesn't have optimization for it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272061/why-doesnt-java-have-optimization-for-tail-recursion-at-all))
- Another way is to [increase stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size) using `-Xss` option
- Or you can add actual depth check to `solveMaze` method, e.g.:

```
  public void showPath() {
    // ...
    if (solveMaze(sol, m.length - 1, 0, exitCords , 0) == false) {
    // ...
  }

  public boolean solveMaze(int[][] sol, int y, int x, int[] exitCords, int depth) {
    if (depth > 64) {
      return false;
    }
    // ...
    solveMaze(sol, y, x, exitCords, depth + 1); 
    // ...  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow error means that your recursion has gone deeper than the language allows.  For a small maze, this shouldn't happen, *unless* you are revisiting locations in the maze.  As your code does not seem to make any effort to avoid that, you might want to fix that.

Comment: Edit the question (proper list, whatever, `code`-style in the text) and you will get the Excavator too ;-)