# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError Recursion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

[screenshot for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D55uY.png)
[screenshot for vm option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Wxe.png)

I am trying to run my program but it's throwing exception (as in screenshot), I searched for it and found it happen's because programs has too many recursive calls and I should increase stack size by setting Xss to be 1mb through,

Help -> edit custom vm option
when i open it it show a message that vm option not created and i should creat by press on ok
so it created but i can't find Xss parameter as screenshot show

I tried changing Xms and Xmx values in VMOptions

Note : i run this this algorithm on graph that has more than 800000 node
so the recursion is finite but happens too much.

Comment: try debugging your program, and find out why it is going in infinite recursion!

Comment: it doesn't have infinite recursion, i run this algorithm on graph that has more than 800000 nodes, so the recursion is finite but happen too much

Comment: can you write your code iteratively rather than using recursion!

Comment: no it require recursion

Comment: any recursion can be coded as loop

Comment: i think i should increase the depth for recursion but i don'tt know how

Comment: i  implement Kosaraju's two path algorithm and i can't be coded as loop

Comment: probably this article will help you in that : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/

Comment: no this article doesn't help me it explains the algorithm and my algorithm work good on test cases

Comment: my implementation as coursera course instructions with recursion

Comment: that link was for iterative version of algorithm !

Comment: probably you should post question on Coursera's Q/A forum for your course, regarding this particular problem

Comment: does you know how to Increase Thread Stack Size (-Xss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add,  -Xss4096k option in vmoption file,This will increase stack size to 4mb. Save it and restart ide.
For more information check,
[How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size)

Comment: np! if above approach does not solve issue, do check with your course community, Coursera communities are very active :)