# How to handle the time complexity for permutation of strings during anagrams search?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, permutation, anagram

I have a program that computes that whether two strings are anagrams or not.
It works fine for inputs of strings below length of 10.
When I input two strings whose lengths are equal and have lengths of more than 10 program runs and doesn't produce an answer .

My concept is that if two strings are anagrams one string must be a permutation of other string.

This program generates the all permutations from one string, and after that it checks is there any matching permutation for the other string. In this case I wanted to ignore cases.
It returns false when there is no matching string found or the comparing strings are not equal in length, otherwise returns true.

```java
public class Anagrams {
    static ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();

    static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        // there is no need for checking these two
        // strings because their length doesn't match
        if (a.length() != b.length())
            return false;

        Anagrams.permute(a, 0, a.length() - 1);

        for (String string : Anagrams.str)
            if (string.equalsIgnoreCase(b))
                // returns true if there is a matching string
                // for b in the permuted string list of a
                return true;
        // returns false if there is no matching string
        // for b in the permuted string list of a
        return false;
    }

    private static void permute(String str, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r)
            // adds the permuted strings to the ArrayList
            Anagrams.str.add(str);
        else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
                str = Anagrams.swap(str, l, i);
                Anagrams.permute(str, l + 1, r);
                str = Anagrams.swap(str, l, i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String swap(String a, int i, int j) {
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i];
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }
}
```

***1.*** I want to know why can't this program process larger strings

***2.*** I want to know how to fix this problem

Can you figure it out?

Comment: if you have a string that is 11 factorial permutations which is 39916800 big number right?, it is processing it, you will eventually get the result pop up on console

Comment: 1) Time and space complexity of your solution is large. As there are n! permutations, where `n` is the length of your string. 

2) You can check whether two strings are anagrams in linear time and constant space complexity.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Yeah I get that I always stuck like these big recursions is there a mechanism that eliminate problems like this

Comment: @jpact So is there a mechanism which handles the situations like this?

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara see solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing it in very expensive way and the time complexity here is exponential because your'e using permutations which requires factorials and factorials grow very fast , as you're doing permutations it will take time to get the output when the input is greater than 10.

`11 factorial = 39916800
12 factorial = 479001600
13 factorial = 6227020800`

and so on...

So don't think you're not getting an output for big numbers you will eventually get it

If you go something like 20-30 factorial i think i will take years to produce any output , if you use loops , with recursion you will overflow the stack.

**fact :** 50 factorial is a number that big it is more than the number of sand grains on earth , and computer surrender when they have to deal with numbers that big.

That is why they make you include special character in passwords to make the number of permutations too big that computers will not able to crack it for years if they try every permutations , and encryption also depends on that weakness of the computers.

So you don't have to and should not  do that to solve it **(because computer are not good very at it)**, it is an overkill

why don't you take each character from one string and match it with every character of other string, it will be quadratic at in worst case.

And if you sort both the strings then you can just say

`string1.equals(string2)`

`true` means **anagram**

`false` means **not anagram**

and it will take linear time,except the time taken in sorting.

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara check the edit, and you can mark it answered, all the best

Comment: But one more question not related to this one, there are many problems that require recursions, and at some times it causes the stack overflow. Is n't there any mechanism to overcome this problem like dynamic programming?

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara no problem requires recursions , if you can do it with recursion then you can also do it iteratively , but recursion sometimes gives a easy and short solution , but if you know that you're going to get in deep recursion then don't use it, also recursion is less efficient then iterative solution because method call is an extra overhead.

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara if you have to use deep recursion then you can also increase the stack size , check this there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem and check whether two strings are anagrams you don't actually need to generate every single permutation of the source string and then match it against the second one. What you can do instead, is count the frequency of each character in the first string, and then verify whether the same frequency applies for the second string.

The solution above requires one pass for each string, hence Θ(n) time complexity. In addition, you need auxiliary storage for counting characters which is Θ(1) space complexity. These are asymptotically tight bounds.

Comment: Auxiliary storage for counting characters is O(n) space complexity, not O(1) space complexity.

Comment: @JimMischel no, you need one storage location per character in your character set (which is usually considered bounded). For example, if your strings are strings of bytes, then only 256 counters are needed, irrespective of string size.

Comment: @PaulHankin Okay, so you need O(|alphabet|), which as you say, is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get arrays of characters from these strings, then [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(char%5B%5D)) them, and then compare the two sorted arrays. This method works with both *regular characters* and *surrogate pairs*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAnagram("ABCD", "DCBA")); // true
    System.out.println(isAnagram("", "")); // true
}
```

```java
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    // invalid incoming data
    if (a == null || b == null
            || a.length() != b.length())
        return false;

    char[] aArr = a.toCharArray();
    char[] bArr = b.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(aArr);
    Arrays.sort(bArr);

    return Arrays.equals(aArr, bArr);
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Check if one array is a subset of the other array - special case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131110/15675591)</sup>