# Ackermann function won't work when m >= 4

Tags: java, recursion

**Wikipedia:** [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)

I'm writing this program for my computer science class and I don't know why it doesn't work. too be clear, the program works when m <= 3.

I've checked that when m = 4 and n = 1, the result should be 65533 so the variable isn't too small. I've tried using int, long, and double.

```
public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(ack(3, 8));
    }

    public static long ack(long m, long n) {
        if (m == 0) {
            return n + 1;
        } else if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
            return ack(m - 1, 1);
        }
        return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What result are you getting? Are you seeing a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`?

Comment: First of all can you describe what your code is intended to do? Secondly, describe the cases when the code fails.

Comment: "doesn't work" is the worst possible description of a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing, is a `StackOverflowError`. You can read more on what causes them and the default stack size etc. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214758/17173476) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size).

In your case, simply increasing the stack size will allow you to run this with the inputs 4, 1. You can achieve this by running your program as follows:

```
javac Recursion.java
java -Xss8m Recursion.java
```

The `-Xss` Flag sets a higher stack size, and you should get the expected output 65533 after a while.