# StackOverflowError when sorting a list of 7 numbers with my quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort

For the following quicksort algorithm:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class quick_sort_demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> my_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter input value. '-1' to exit the adding process. ");
            int val = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (val == -1) {
                break;
            } else {
                my_arr.add(val);
            }
        }
        quick_sort(my_arr);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> quick_sort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        if (arr.size() <= 1) {
            return arr;
        }
        int pivot_index = (int) (Math.random() * arr.size());
        int pivot = arr.get(pivot_index);
        ArrayList<Integer> left_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> right_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            int element = arr.get(i);
            if (element > pivot) {
                right_arr.add(element);
            } else {
                left_arr.add(element);
            }
        }
        left_arr = quick_sort(left_arr);
        right_arr = quick_sort(right_arr);
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        result.addAll(left_arr);
        result.add(pivot);
        result.addAll(right_arr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error repeatedly:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.base/java.util.Random.next(Random.java:209)
        at java.base/java.util.Random.nextDouble(Random.java:463)
        at java.base/java.lang.Math.random(Math.java:865)
        at quick_sort_demo.quick_sort(quick_sort_demo.java:23)
        at quick_sort_demo.quick_sort(quick_sort_demo.java:35)
```

My exact inputs for the program were as follows: {6,15,32,643,6543,534232,232,-1}

I tried asking CHATGPT but I couldn't get a helpful answer for the specific error I encountered. I don't understand why I'm getting a stackoverflow error as the recursive method should be calling itself without issue until the 'arr.size()' returns something <= 1. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Is my algorithm wrong and why am I getting a recursion error?

Comment: The error trace is incomplete.

Comment: Note that QuickSort must be performed in-place. Which your code does not do.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I'm confused on what error trace means in this context, do you mean I didn't provide the full error message or is it something else? Also what does the error trace have anything to do with my algorithm?

Comment: "what does the error trace have anything to do with my algorithm": you mean there is no error to worry about ??

Comment: When you are partitioning your elements, you will at a point encounter the pivot element, and since it is not greater than itself, you will put it in the `left_arr`. After the recursive calls you are adding both all the elements from `left_arr` including the pivot element and the pivot element itself to the result. So the pivot element gets duplicated. Also if the pivot happens to be the max element, all the elements go into `left_arr`, which will cause recursion with a list equal to the original one. Whether any of this can cause your stack overflow, I don’t know.

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: I cannot reproduce exactly. In one run your code sorted your input into `[6, 6, 15, 15, 32, 32, 32, 232, 232, 643, 643, 6543, 6543, 534232, 534232]`. Note the repeated elements. However when I enter input 1, 2, 1, -1, I get a stack overflow error that looks like yours. Can it be that you observed it when by mistake you entered the same element twice?

Comment: @user16320675 True. I believe that that’s why we observe the stack overflow if there are equal elements in the list. If there are not, the random component will save us sooner or later and in the vast majority of cases before the stack overflow hits us.

Comment: @Ole agreed - just tested and also could not reproduce the problem with posted input, but for sure if replacing last element by `6` (a duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### code runs fine

well **almost** fine, there is a bug in your code

```
left_arr = quick_sort(left_arr);
right_arr = quick_sort(right_arr);
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
result.addAll(left_arr);
result.add(pivot); //BUG HERE
result.addAll(right_arr);
```

when you split left/right you already add your `pivot` into the `left_arr` - so no need to add it twice, since

```
if (element > pivot) {
    right_arr.add(element);
} else {
    left_arr.add(element); //pivot itself is NOT bigger than pivot and will be added here
}
```

alternatively you can `remove` the pivot from the list: `int pivot = arr.remove(pivot_index);`

### about java.lang.StackOverflowError

well - your code is working fine, on my machine so i guess you have to setup your computer properly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size) for further details (sorry for that link-only answer)

Comment: I think you are closer than you think: The bug you mention causes the stack overflow asked about if I enter the same number twice in the input.

Comment: i fixed that code on my side already, so i didn't stumble over it ^^