# finding greatest prime factor using recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion, prime-factoring

have wrote the code for what i see to be a good algorithm for finding the greatest prime factor for a large number using recursion. My program crashes with any number greater than 4 assigned to the variable huge_number though. I am not good with recursion and the assignment does not allow any sort of loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long prime_factor(int n, long long huge_number);

int main (void)
{
    int n = 2;
    long long huge_number =  60085147514;
    long long largest_prime = 0;

    largest_prime = prime_factor(n, huge_number);
    printf("%ld\n", largest_prime);

    return 0;
}

long long prime_factor (int n, long long huge_number)
{
    if (huge_number / n == 1)
        return huge_number;
    else if (huge_number % n == 0)
        return prime_factor (n, huge_number / n);        
    else
        return prime_factor (n++, huge_number);
}
```

any info as to why it is crashing and how i could improve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even fixing the problem of using post-increment so that the recursion continues forever, this is not a good fit for a recursive solution - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776035/is-there-ever-a-time-you-would-not-use-recursion/3776051#3776051) for why, but it boils down to how fast you can reduce the search space.

While your division of `huge_number` whittles it down pretty fast, the vast majority of recursive calls are done by simply incrementing `n`. That means you're going to use a *lot* of stack space.

You would be better off either:

- using an iterative solution where you won't blow out the stack (if you just want to solve the problem) <sup>(a)</sup>; or
- finding a more suitable problem for recursion if you're just trying to learn recursion.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> An example of such a beast, modeled on your recursive solution, is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long prime_factor_i (int n, long long huge_number) {
    while (n < huge_number) {
        if (huge_number % n == 0) {
            huge_number /= n;
            continue;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return huge_number;
}

int main (void) {
    int n = 2;
    long long huge_number =  60085147514LL;
    long long largest_prime = 0;

    largest_prime = prime_factor_i (n, huge_number);
    printf ("%lld\n", largest_prime);

    return 0;
}
```

---

As can be seen from the output of that iterative solution, the largest factor is `10976461`. That means the final batch of recursions in your recursive solution would require a stack depth of ten *million* stack frames, not something most environments will contend with easily.

If you really *must* use a recursive solution, you can reduce the stack space to the square root of that by using the fact that you don't *have* to check all the way up to the number, but only up to its square root.

In addition, other than `2`, every other prime number is odd, so you can further halve the search space by only checking two plus the odd numbers.

A recursive solution taking those two things into consideration would be:

```
long long prime_factor_r (int n, long long huge_number) {
    // Debug code for level checking.

    // static int i = 0;
    // printf ("recursion level = %d\n", ++i);

    // Only check up to square root.

    if (n * n >= huge_number)
        return huge_number;

    // If it's a factor, reduce the number and try again.

    if (huge_number % n == 0)
        return prime_factor_r (n, huge_number / n);

    // Select next "candidate" prime to check against, 2 -> 3,
    //   2n+1 -> 2n+3 for all n >= 1.

    if (n == 2)
        return prime_factor_r (3, huge_number);

    return prime_factor_r (n + 2, huge_number);
}
```

You can see I've also removed the (awkward, in my opinion) construct:

```
if something then
    return something
else
    return something else
```

I much prefer the less massively indented code that comes from:

```
if something then
    return something
return something else
```

But that's just personal preference. In any case, that gets your recursion level down to 1662 (uncomment the debug code to verify) rather than ten million, a rather sizable reduction but still not perfect. That runs okay in my environment.

Comment: it is an assignment based on recursion in which i cannot use any form of looping. this is what essentially has me stuck.

Comment: @TristanPearce, you can lower the recursion level requirement using two simple tricks  (1) checking only 2 and the odd numbers, and (2) only checking up to the _square root_ of the number (this ones the real winner) - see the update.

Comment: thank you so much. I knew there was something to do with the square root based upon research online. That makes a lot more sense than checking all numbers.

Comment: quick question to avoid compiler warnings. Is it proper to use %lld for long long variables?

Comment: @TristanPearce, yes, you should be using lld for long long types.

Comment: @TristanPearce Note that a recent enough gcc with `-O3` transforms the (tail) recursive function into a loop. And the computation finishes almost instantaneously since ~5.5 million iterations is not much. Of course the square-root and oddness optimisations are still good, but with a decent compiler, you don't need to worry about stack frames *in such cases as this*.

Answer (score 1):

You meant `n+1` instead of `n++`. `n++` increments `n` *after* using it, so the recursive call gets the original value of `n`.

Comment: i just tried both ways and it still crashes. using ++n mading it take a few extra seconds though.

Comment: @TristanPearce Yes, `++n` would work, but keep in mind that the particular instance of `n` which is getting incremented would never be used again (since the call in which it is a formal parameter returns immediately after making the recursive invocation).

Comment: @TristanPearce The code is actually correct with `++n` or `n+1`. Your stack just can't handle the `huge_number` you gave it. Try a smaller number - it works for dozens now.

Comment: @TristanPearce Last hint: try printing `n` and `huge_number` at the top of `prime_factor`. That way you can watch the code do its thing as it runs.

Comment: That will still blow out the stack, simply because the vast number of recursions are of the n++ variety, not the huge /= n variety. The last factor-find of that number will need about ten million stack levels.

Comment: i have no idea how to lower the amount of recursive calls at this point. i know the chance of it working with the huge number is low because it crashes with just 5 which i dont understand.

Comment: @TristanPearce With the change I suggested, it does not crash with five. But if you want it work with larger numbers, use the *Euclidean Algorithm* instead of what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing stack, because n++ post-increments the value, making a recursive call with the same values as in the current invocation.

Answer (score 0):

the crash reason is stack overflow. I add a counter to your program and execute it(on ubuntu 10.04 gcc 4.4.3) the counter stop at "218287" before core dump. the better solution is using loop instead of recursion.