# Java endless recursion and StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Sorry, for probably a dumb question, I'm new to Java.

Is there a way to make an endless recursion in Java, somithing like:

```
public void sillyMethod()
{
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
    sillyMethod();

}
```

it throws StackOverflowError, but I really want to run it endless. Is there any way to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you really want "endless", go for iteration.

Comment: Read about [Stack Overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) and you will see that you can't

Comment: @Anon Iteration? That wouldn't be endless, would it? I mean, that's the whole point of iteration, you count something

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations

Comment: @Sean: I use iteration as basically synonymous with loops. Additionally, just because you're counting doesn't mean you ever stop... `for(i = 0; ; i++) ;` loops forever in any language with silent wraparound on overflows.

Comment: @Anon I guess my definition of iterating is more semantically equivalent to what the Iterable interface in Java does, but yours seems to be the correct definition

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no, (but mostly no! :)

*No, it's not possible (the most sensible answer):*
 For every call, there will be an activation record pushed onto the JVM call stack. This takes a non-zero amount of memory, thus you will at some point run out of memory, at which point a StackOverflowException will be thrown.

*Yes, it is possible (the super-theoretical answer):*
 There is nothing in the Java Language Specification that explicitly says that you should eventually run into a StackOverflowException. This means that if you find a **cleaver enough compiler, it may be intelligent enough to compile this into a loop**.

---

A related question would be, ["Does the JVM support tail-call optimization."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations) The answer to this question is, "no, not at moment, but it's not ruled out for future versions".

Comment: ...then the activation record would be slightly larger. But if the recursion can be transformed into a loop, what does it matter?

Comment: *"... clever enough compiler ..."*  the real technical challenge in Java is implementing tail-call optimization in a way that does not break the Java security model, etc.

Comment: @Stephen C, could you give an example of how it is related to the security model?

Answer (score 1):

As others above have said, infinite recursion will eventually lead to a stack overflow, at least as far as the JVM implementation is concerned.

You could do something like this, which is similar, but avoids the stack expansion by spawning a new thread right before the old one dies.

```
public class SillyClass implements Runnable {

private final int count;

public SillyClass(int cnt) {
    this.count = cnt;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new SillyClass(0));
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(count);
    Thread t = new Thread(new SillyClass(count + 1));
    t.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not recursively, no. It does imply creating an ever-increasing call stack, and eventually you will run out of memory to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

With Java, you cannot do this. However, tail call optimization in languages (esp. functional ones such as Ocaml), you can do this since it internally turns it into a loop.