# Tail recursion with Groovy

Tags: groovy, recursion, tail-recursion, factorial, tail-call-optimization

I coded 3 factorial algorithms:

1. I expect to fail by stack overflow. No problem.
2. I try a tail recursive call, and convert the previous algorithm from recursive to iterative. It doesn't work, but I don't understand why.
3. I use `trampoline()` method and it works fine as I expect.

```
def factorial

factorial = { BigInteger n ->  
    if (n == 1) return 1  
    n * factorial(n - 1)  
}  
factorial(1000)  // stack overflow  

factorial = { Integer n, BigInteger acc = 1 ->  
    if (n == 1) return acc  
    factorial(n - 1, n * acc)  
}  
factorial(1000)  // stack overflow, why?  

factorial = { Integer n, BigInteger acc = 1 ->  
    if (n == 1) return acc  
    factorial.trampoline(n - 1, n * acc)  
}.trampoline()  
factorial(1000)  // It works.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 2.3 Groovy supports tail recursion with the @TailRecursive annotation for methods:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-more-efficient

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There is no tail recursion in Java, and hence there is none in Groovy either (without using something [like `trampoline()`](http://www.jroller.com/vaclav/entry/jumping_the_groovy_trampoline) as you have shown)</strike>

The closest I have seen to this, is [an AST transformation](http://blog.johanneslink.net/2011/02/11/tail-recursion-optimization-with-groovys-ast-transformations/) which cleverly wraps the return recursion into a while loop

**Edit**

You're right, Java (and hence Groovy) do support this sort of tail-call iteration, however, it doesn't seem to work with Closures...

This code however (using a method rather than a closure for the `fact` call):

```
public class Test {
  BigInteger fact( Integer a, BigInteger acc = 1 ) {
    if( a == 1 ) return acc
    fact( a - 1, a * acc )
  }
  static main( args ) {
    def t = new Test()
    println "${t.fact( 1000 )}"
  }
}
```

When saved as `Test.groovy` and executed with `groovy Test.groovy` runs, and prints the answer:

```
402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

As a guess, I would say that the JVM does not know how to optimise closures (like it does with methods), so this tail call does not get optimised out in the bytecode before it is executed

Comment: [JVM has limitations in tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/105834/462015) but there are [tail recursion in Java](http://books.google.ca/books?id=iPHtCfZQyqQC&lpg=PP1&dq=java%20performance%20tuning&pg=PT230#v=onepage&q&f=false) if you implemented, like me in the second option

Comment: @Arturo You're right of course...  I have updated my answer with some extra findings...

Comment: I have the same problem but now with methods instead of closures. Try your example with the recursive approach and works!

Comment: [Trampoline](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#trampoline()) [works](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cool-stuff-groovy-18) [with Closures](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/groovy-goodness-recursion-with-closure.html) as of [Groovy 1.8](http://www.solutionsiq.com/resources/agileiq-blog/bid/72880/Programming-with-Groovy-Trampoline-and-Memoize)

Comment: If you replace `1000` with `50000` this example still throws a `StackOverflowError` for me (Java 7). Using a loop works fine with `50000`.

Comment: Sorry for the nit-picking, but why `println "${t.fact( 1000 )}"` - why  not: `println t.fact( 1000 )` ?

Comment: No reason at all, and looking back I'm not sure what I was thinking ;-)