# Recursion for nested loops

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

jIs there a way to create a recursive function of the following code?

```
for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<1000000; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<1000000; k++){
            //Do something using i,j and k
        }
    }
}
```

I need it to combine every possible sequence of numbers. eg: (0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,0)

It took about 10 hours to pass through this loops, so i have to simplify it and i think a recursive function could do it.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way?  Sure.  Do I see a reason to?  No.  Could you elaborate as to why recursion would be better than iteration in this case?

Comment: If I am not wrong, everything that can be done using iteration can be done using recursion, you just need to think of a way to achieve it.

Comment: Also, you use 'i' in the termination of the 'j' for loop.

Just saying.

Comment: @Abu In theory: yes. In practice: it depends. Java does not support TCO, so recursion has a finite depth in Java.

Comment: recursion does no improvement in the performance. its just a 'cleaner' way of writing repetitive/looping instruction.

Comment: I think parallel processing would be a better idea. If you have 8 cores, you can (in a perfect world) drop the execution time to 10/8 = 1.25 hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

In theory, every iterative loop can be converted to a recursive call (with either an infinite stack or via a [tail-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)), however:

1. Recursion is *not faster* than iteration - the time complexity is identical
2. Java does not support [TCO](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization) and thus does not support such deep recursive calls - tens of dozens: yes, millions: absolutely not

In this case it takes a long time because it *loops a ridiculous number of times*. The brute force algorithm is O(n<sup>c</sup>), where c is 3 - that is, [the bounds are polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_time#Polynomial_time) (this is not good) and n is "relatively large". That's *a lot* of [wasted CPU cycles](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-L-yq0Q3RhRs/UAQocCIoP-I/AAAAAAAAAQE/CQSUddkeBDs/s1600/4677611-burning-processor-on-motherboard.jpg).

Considering that this many permutations is *generally* not sane to use/store directly anyway, it might be beneficial to *revisit the original problem* and derive an approach with a reasonable time complexity. For instance, there is a much better way to count permutations ..

Comment: @Dukeling 1. [Constants are factored out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ("wall-clock" time may differ for a particular n) 2. Sure, it's possible to recurse in only one dimension.

Comment: Oh right, complexity. Updated comment - 1) The time complexity may be identical, but, in Java, recursion is generally slower ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2651200/1711796) briefly mentions it), although only by a smallish constant factor, but, given the simplicity of the given code, it could make a greatly significant difference. 2) The way I'm thinking of only requires a recursion depth of 3, not millions. Not sure how else you'd want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why convert that to recursive, that's gonna make it run slower ..

But you can try this:

```
public static void recursiveLoop (int i, int j, int k, int w, int h, int d)
{

    /* code .. */

    /* increment i,j,k */
    if (k == d)
    {
        k = 0;
        j++;
    }

    if (j == h)
    {
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }

    if (i == w)
    {
        return; // Stop
    }

    recursiveLoop(i,j,k);

}
```

But the compiler will change it into something like this:

```
public static void recursiveLoop (int i, int j, int k, int w, int h, int d)
{

    do
    {

        /* code .. */

        /* increment i,j,k */
        if (k == d)
        {
            k = 0;
            j++;
        }

        if (j == h)
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }

    }while (i != w);

}
```

Comment: `"the compiler will change it into this"` - I strongly doubt that. They may functionally be the same, but the compiler will not convert a recursive function into iterative (at least it won't in Java).

Comment: @Dukeling You're right, I'm not sure about most of them, but I know that converting tail-recursion into a while-loop is a common compiler syntax-optimization, what is highly unlikely is the modulo tail-recursion optimization

Comment: Note that Java / the JVM doesn't support tail call optimization. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations). Also note that because the check is at the end, it will probably be `do { ... } while ();`, not `while () { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following thing Recursion , go through this for detail .
[Is recursion ever faster than looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651112/is-recursion-ever-faster-than-looping)

So as you tagged Java , recursion is more expensive over iteration as stack memory has to to allocated . So, if your intention is to record those permutation , then better you store them to file for later use . And it depends on your problem statement one can specify more accurate answer  for this .