# sum of absolute matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, tail-recursion

Here is a question from previous **HackerEarth** **Challenge** -

Roy has a matrix of size NxN. Rows and Columns are numbered from 0 to N-1.
jth column of ith row contains absolute difference between i and j.
In other words, Matrix[i][j] = abs(i-j) where 0 ≤ i, j < N.
Your task is to find sum of this matrix i.e.

```
sum = 0
for i=0 to N-1
    for j=0 to N-1
        sum += Matrix[i][j]
```

and here is my solution to this problem -

```
public static long getSum(int num, long acc) {
        if (num == 1)
            return acc;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        sum = sum * 2;
        return getSum(num - 1, acc + sum);
    }
```

But this function fails for large number like say anything greater than 4500. I get Stack Over Flow Error. 
Here I have tried two things basically to keep the code optimized -

1. use tail recursion, and
2. keep running time of this function of order 'n'

So please tell me if I have achieved the two things here correctly. If yes what else can I do to optimize this code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix has very simple structure (I draw only top right half, bottom left is the same, mirrored)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
. 0 1 2 3 4 ...
. . 0 1 2 3 ...
. . . 0 1 2 ...
. . . . 0 1 ...
. . . . . 0 ...
```

It is clear that Kth row contains arithmetic progression `0..(N - K - 1)`, so it's sum is

```
Sk = (N - K - 1) * (N - K) / 2
```

and overall sum is (O(N) solution)

```
S = 2 * Sum[k = 0..N-1] (Sk)
```

Moreover, while sum of every row is 'triangular' number, sum of triangular numbers is '[Tetrahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number)', and there is closed formula, that leads to O(1) solution

```
S = 2 * ((N-1)*N*(N+1)/6) = N*(N+1)*(N-1)/3
```

Example: `for N=4   S = 3*4*5/3 = 20`

Comment: This is one nice answer!

Comment: Thanks MBo for your answer. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## Tail recursion

Tail recursion does not protect you from stack overflow in Java. Some other languages can recognise [tail-calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and optimize them during compilation so they do not extend the stack.

> ...tail call optimization is hard to do in the JVM because of the security model and the need to always have a stack trace available.

(From [Does the JVM prevent tail call optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations))

It is however easy to replace tail recursions with a loop:

```
public static long getSum(int num, long acc) {
    while (num > 1) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        sum = sum * 2;
        //set up values for next loop
        num--;
        acc += sum;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

## Big-O

> keep running time of this function of order 'n'

You have not achieved this. It is clear to see there are 2 nested loops over `num`, and `num` is decreasing, I think this makes it *O(n log n)*

Comment: Thanks weston, for sharing this information about tail recursion in java.