# Issue modifying control from static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are a few questions on here that are similar, but they didn't work for me.

I have a custom drop down list on a page, the page name is `WebForm1`. On `WebForm1` I have an assembly reference to it: `<%@ Register Assembly="GroupDropDownList" Namespace="GroupDropDownList" TagPrefix="cc1" %>`

I then have a static method like this:

```
    public static void Populate_Country_DDL(System.Web.UI.Page page)
        {
            GroupDropDownList
                .GroupDropDownList ddlCountry =
 ((GroupDropDownList.GroupDropDownList)page.FindControl("ddlCountry"));

            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                var country = db.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.Text);

                ddlCountry.DataSource = country; //Error here
```

On `WebForm1` i'm trying to access the static method like this:

```
Utility.Populate_Country_DDL(this.Page);
```

The problem is that I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I put a using statement in my utility class for `GroupDropDownList`

`GroupDropDownList` simply allows me to put option groups inside a drop down list.

**Update:** To fix the problem I modified my utility method to take a `ContentPlaceHolder` instead of `Page` class, and then in my calling method I found the ContentPlaceHolder within the current pages MasterPage like this:

```
Utility.Populate_Country_DDL(
                (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master
                .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"));
```

Comment: Please post full version of method and specify in which line you get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the control you are looking at the page was not found. Are you sure the name is correct?

`FindControl` method does not go down the controls hierarchy, so you'll have to write your own method which searches through all controls on the page.

E.g. recursive version:

```
    public static Control FindControlRecursively(Control parent, string id)
    {
        Control control = parent.FindControl(id);

        if (control != null)
        {
            return control;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in parent.Controls)
            {
                control = FindControlRecursively(childControl, id);
                if (control != null)
                {
                    return control;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Or version without recursion:

```
    public static Control DeepFindControl(Control parent, string id)
    {
        Queue<Control> queue = new Queue<Control>();

        queue.Enqueue(parent);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            Control currentParent = queue.Dequeue();

            Control control = currentParent.FindControl(id);

            if (control != null)
            {
                return control;
            }

            foreach (Control childControl in parent.Controls)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(childControl);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: the non recursion method is interesting. Any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: @Nuick: It is just the different way of traversing the tree of controls. In this case I would say that there is no difference which one you pick.

Comment: @Nick: you can also see this question on recursion vs loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660337/recursion-vs-loops

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx):

> The FindControl method can be used to
>   access a control whose ID is not
>   available at design time. The method
>   searches only the page's immediate, or
>   top-level, container; **it does not
>   recursively search for controls in
>   naming containers contained on the
>   page. To access controls in a
>   subordinate naming container, call the
>   FindControl method of that container.**

You can only use `FindControl()` on the direct parent of the control you are looking for, otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: So if `WebForm1` is within a master page then I need to find the contetnt place holder for that masterpage?