# jquery .on gets Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read almost every SO question about

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

but non worked for me.

My problem is that I'm changing some `div` text after loading it, which is working with me. However, the console is displaying the `Uncaught RangeError` error.
this is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#report-error').on("DOMNodeInserted DOMCharacterDataModified" ,function(){
                $('#report-error').text("error happened");

            });           
 </script>
```

and this is my HTML after the jquery had been applied:

```
<div id="report-error" class="report-div error" 
style="display: block;">error happened
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks good here http://jsfiddle.net/u7nU5/

Comment: @iJay - then why am I getting this error?!

Comment: if you can create the issue in jsfiddle..it would be helpful for us to look into it, else we don't have any thing to debug ....hope u got the point

Comment: @iJay - working on it.

Comment: You need to trigger the event first to replicate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/u7nU5/1/

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483895/infinite-loop-in-functional-programming

Comment: @David - I'm sorry, but I didn't get the point. can you justify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens because the `DOMNodeInserted` event is triggered when you run the jQuery method `.text()`, since this method inserts a text node into the container.

So in short - the handler will invoke it’s own event...

You could solve it by using [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `on`, but the side effects depends on the rest of your logic.

```
$('#report-error').one("DOMNodeInserted" ,function(){
    $('#report-error').text("error happened");
});
```

Comment: Infinite loop through tail recursion.

Comment: +1 Great point, but is it solvable, or should I just leave it as it is with no harm included?!

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I added a possible solution.

Comment: @David - `.one` works fine for 1 time per event. then, my function will not be triggered.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan OK then, well now that you know what the problem is I’m sure you can figure out a solution... using a different DIV for error reporting comes to mind.