# Return item at position x in a list

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I was reading this post [While or Tail Recursion in F#, what to use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797241/while-or-tail-recursion-in-f-what-to-use-when) were several people say that the 'functional way' of doing things is by using maps/folds and higher order functions instead of recursing and looping.

I have this function that returns the item at position x in a list:

```
let rec getPos l c =  if c = 0 then List.head l else getPos (List.tail l) (c - 1)
```

how can it be converted to be more functional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a primitive list function (also known as `List.nth`).

It is okay to use recursion, especially when creating the basic building blocks. Although it would be nicer with pattern matching instead of `if-else`, like this:

```
let rec getPos l c =
   match l with
   | h::_ when c = 0 -> h
   | _::t -> getPos t (c-1)
   | [] -> failwith "list too short"
```

It is possible to express this function with `List.fold`, however the result is less clear than the recursive version.

Comment: Nice, but I'd rather do ´| h::[] -> h´ for the first match condition

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by more functional.

Are you rolling this yourself as a learning exercise?

If not, you could just try this:

```
> let mylist = [1;2;3;4];;
> let n = 2;;
> mylist.[n];;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is already pretty functional since it uses a tail-recursive function instead of an imperative loop construct. However, it also looks like something a Scheme programmer might have written because you're using `head` and `tail`.

I suspect you're really asking how to write it in a more idiomatic ML style. The answer is to use pattern matching:

```
let rec getPos list n =
    match list with
    | hd::tl ->
        if n = 0 then hd
        else getPos tl (n - 1)
    | [] -> failWith "Index out of range."
```

The recursion on the structure of the list is now revealed in the code. You also get a warning if the pattern matching is non-exhaustive so you're forced to deal with the index too big error.

You're right that functional programming also encourages the use of combinators like map or fold (so called points-free style). But too much of it just leads to unreadable code. I don't think it's warranted in this case.

Of course, Benjol is right, in practice you would just write `mylist.[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use high-order functions for this, you could do:

```
let nth n = Seq.take (n+1) >> Seq.fold (fun _ x -> Some x) None

let nth n = Seq.take (n+1) >> Seq.reduce (fun _ x -> x)
```

But the idea is really to have basic constructions and combine them build whatever you want. Getting the nth element of a sequence is clearly a basic block that you should use. If you want the nth item, as Benjol mentioned, do `myList.[n]`.

For building basic constructions, there's nothing wrong to use recursion or mutable loops (and often, you *have* to do it this way).

Answer (score 0):

Not as a practical solution, but as an exercise, here is one of the ways to express `nth` via `foldr` or, in F# terms, `List.foldBack`:

```
let myNth n xs =
    let step e f = function |0 -> e |n -> f (n-1)
    let error _ = failwith "List is too short"
    List.foldBack step xs error n
```