# count significant digits in integer

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

To provide context, I'm very new to C#, and am currently working my way through Wiley's Software Development Fundamentals.  The question is the following:

> You are developing a library of utility functions for your application. You need to write a method that takes an integer and counts the number of significant digits in it. You need to create a recursive program to solve the problem.  How would you write such a program?.

I think I have created a solution to this question, however I'm unsure if this is correct as I don't know how to return a value stating *"this is how many significant digits"*.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dig(55535);
    }
    public static int dig(int x)
    {
        if (x < 10)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1 + dig(x / 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"however I'm unsure if this is correct as I don't know how to return a value stating "this is how many significant digits"."*?

Comment: That there is an output to the console saying "55535 has 5 significant digits".  Or have I missed the point of the exercise?

Comment: So you can write the recursive function but are not able to use `Console.WriteLine` ? Are you sure that it is **your** code?

Comment: How can you not see that the answer is 5? #confused

Comment: I can use the Console.Writeline, but where?  I've tried this before the if function, and after the "return 1 + dig(x / 10).

Comment: Recursive program is not the bes option check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209/recursion-or-iteration

Comment: What result do you expect? What is the actual result when you run your code?

Comment: @DanielVorph Telling a student to not solve a problem according the instructor's guidelines isn't very constructive.

Comment: @Jon Do you understand what a "return value" is? Do you know how to use the return value after you have called a function?

Comment: I can see that the answer is 5, and if I use a breakpoint, x has the digits 55535 at the end of the program.  To be honest I'm unsure if I need to Console.Writeline the result, or is the code shown above sufficient as an answer to the question?

I understand what return value does, terminates that part of the code and returns to the calling method i.e. the if statement.

Comment: @Jon If I make a guess, you even don't know how to calculate it for a number entered by user.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't, I'm very new to this :), and trying to self-teach (Going round in circles as you can see by my confusion)

Comment: Your requirement is to write a function that count how many significant digits are present in an integer. Are you able to determine if the `dig` function is a correct answer to your requirement? (Test, test, test) Nowhere there is a requirement to write it down somewhere. So, in this particular case your main function is just used as a test to verify the entry point of dig and you can add here a simple WriteLine to check the result but it is not required.

Comment: wait. Up vote for what? `Console.WriteLine()`?. Duplicate question and very simple answer that can be find in google. and some people down vote questions that are clear and is not easy to find solution. I just dont get it!

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `Main` function and use [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) to write the result to the output window.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // storing the return value of the function in to a variable
    int result = dig(55535); 

    //print the variable
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    //or call Console.WriteLine(dig(55535));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this had me stuck.  Got it working now.

Cheers for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Console.WriteLine()` in your `Main()` method to print to the console.

Pass your call to `dig()` as a parameter to `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 55535;
        Console.WriteLine("Number {0} has {1} significant digits", value, dig(value));
    }
    public static int dig(int x)
    {
        // Exactly as you have it
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this kind of downvoting and voting to delete an answer is kind of bullying in community and I will report it to the moderators

Comment: Some people think homework-type questions are off-topic and shouldn't be answered, and they will downvote. Most of these questions are *terrible*, but this one is actually decent, OP showed his effort and is not asking for a plain solution. Yes, it's trivial but meets the guidelines IMHO, I see no reason it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

While answers like “look at the return value in the debugger” or

```
Console.WriteLine("Number {0} has {1} significant digits", value, dig(value));
```

will answer the question you posed, this is not a good strategy for the future. It may be feasible to have a person inspect a single output for a single variable, but this does not scale to projects involving hundreds (or thousands) of functions with thousands (or billions) of possible return values.

Eventually you will have to implement [automated tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); this is where the computer tests your output and alerts you when something goes wrong.

The topic is a large one, but you can implement a simple example like so:

```
public static void Main(string[] args
{
    var tests = new []
    {
        new []{0, 1},
        new []{1, 1},
        new []{10, 2},
        new []{100, 3}
    };

    foreach (var p in tests)
        if (dig(p[0]) != p[1]) Console.WriteLine("dig({0}) == {1}", p[0], p[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not use recursion, but is a solution to the more general case of counting significant digits in a number. This uses loose rules since it's not possible to know how many trailing zeroes after a decimal point are intended when dealing with non-strings.

```
public int CountSignificantDigits(decimal num)
{
    if (num == 0) return 1;
    if (num < 0) num = -num;
    while (num < 1m) num *= 10;
    string numStr = num.ToString().Replace(".","");
    for (int i = numStr.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (numStr[i] != '0')
            return numStr.Length - (numStr.Length - i) + 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As perhaps already noted, the original code does not account for the integer trailing zeros. This might be an another approach.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
            Console.Write("Number = ");
            int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int abs_number = Math.Abs(number);

            int numTrailingZeros = 0;
            bool check_ntz = true;

            int ndigits = GetSignificantDigits(abs_number, ref check_ntz, ref numTrailingZeros);

            if (numTrailingZeros == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Number of signficant figures: {0}", ndigits);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Number of signficant figures: between {0} and {1}", ndigits, ndigits + numTrailingZeros);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to terminate, any other to continue.");
            Console.WriteLine();
    }
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    return;
}

static int GetSignificantDigits(int n, ref bool check_ntz, ref int ntz)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        int new_n = (int)(n / 10);

        if (check_ntz)
        {
            if (n % 10 == 0)
            {
                ntz++;
                return GetSignificantDigits(new_n, ref check_ntz, ref ntz);
            }
            else
            {
                check_ntz = false;
                return 1 + GetSignificantDigits(new_n, ref check_ntz, ref ntz);
            }
        }
        else
            return 1 + GetSignificantDigits(new_n, ref check_ntz, ref ntz);
    }
}
```

[image]