# Quick sort recursive/iterative speed variation and how to graph them on C++?

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, quicksort

I'm a second semester computer science engineering student and I had to measure the time taken for recursive/iterative quick sort implementations to sort vectors of length 1-500 and graph using C++ for my university coursework.

I expected the recursive quick sort to be slower and iterative quick sort to be quicker. But the opposite happened when i plotted the graphs. Recursive implementation was slightly faster. How could this happen? Is there a problem with my quick sort algorithms or the way I measured execution time?

I will share the code I used to measure execution time on C++ and the code I used to plot the graph. BTW I couldn't graph it on C++ no matter how hard I tried as I'm very new to C++. So, for graph plotting, I used python. Any help regarding how to graph this using C++ is also golden. (I tried to plot using Gnuplot, I followed YouTube guides, read online articles but nothing gave me a clear idea)

I use a Ryzen 7 6800H 3.2GHz CPU and a DDR5 4800MHz 16GB RAM.

C++ code for measuring execution time

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

//function to partition the array
int partition(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    //pick the rightmost element as a pivot from the array
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int partIndex = low;

    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        //if current element is smaller than or equal to the pivot
        if (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[partIndex]);
            partIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[partIndex], arr[high]);
    return partIndex;
}

//recursive quick sort function
void recursivequickSort(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    //when low is less than high
    if (low < high) {
        int partIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
        //smaller elements than pivot go left and
        //higher elements go right
        recursivequickSort(arr, low, partIndex - 1);
        recursivequickSort(arr, partIndex + 1, high);
    }
}

//iterative Quicksort routine
void iterativeQuicksort(vector<int>& arr, int n)
{
    //create a stack of std::pairs
    stack<pair<int, int>> s;

    //get the low and high index of the given array
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;

    //push the low and high index of the array into the stack
    s.push(make_pair(low, high));

    //loop till stack is empty
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        low = s.top().first, high = s.top().second;
        s.pop();

        //rearrange elements across pivot
        //lower to left, higher to right
        int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);

        if (pivot - 1 > low) {
            s.push(make_pair(low, pivot - 1));
        }

        if (pivot + 1 < high) {
            s.push(make_pair(pivot + 1, high));
        }
    }
}

//write the lists to a file
void writeListToFile(const std::vector<int>& list, int length) {
    std::ofstream outputFile("processed_lists.txt", std::ios::app); // Open file in append mode

    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open the file." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Write the processed list to the file
    outputFile << "list with length " << length << " = [";
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
        outputFile << list[i] << ", ";
    }
    outputFile << list[length - 1] << "]\n";

    outputFile.close(); // Close the file
}

//function to generate a random vector of given length
std::vector<int> generateRandomVector(int length) {
    std::vector<int> randomVector;

    // Seed the random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // Define the distribution for random integers (range from -100 to 100, for example)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(-10000, 10000);

    // Generate random elements and fill the vector
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        randomVector.push_back(dis(gen));
    }
    return randomVector;
}

// Function to call both iterative and recursive merge sort on a given vector and return an array with the execution times
array<double, 2> sortingComparison(vector<int>& arr, int numTrials) {
    // Copy the input vector for recursive merge sort
    vector<int> recursiveArr = arr;
    vector<int> iterativeArr = arr;

    vector<int> quickRecursiveTimes;
    vector<int> quickIterativeTimes;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++) {

        auto startIterative = high_resolution_clock::now();
        iterativeQuicksort(iterativeArr, iterativeArr.size());
        auto stopIterative = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto quickIterativeTime = duration_cast<microseconds>(stopIterative - startIterative);
        quickIterativeTimes.push_back(quickIterativeTime.count());

        auto startRecursive = high_resolution_clock::now();
        recursivequickSort(recursiveArr, 0, recursiveArr.size() - 1);
        auto stopRecursive = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto quickRecursiveTime = duration_cast<microseconds>(stopRecursive - startRecursive);
        quickRecursiveTimes.push_back(quickRecursiveTime.count());

    }

    // Calculate the sum of execution times for each sorting algorithm
    long long sumQuickRecursive = accumulate(quickRecursiveTimes.begin(), quickRecursiveTimes.end(), 0LL);
    long long sumQuickIterative = accumulate(quickIterativeTimes.begin(), quickIterativeTimes.end(), 0LL);

    // Calculate the average execution time for each sorting algorithm
    double averageQuickRecursive = static_cast<double>(sumQuickRecursive) / numTrials;
    double averageQuickIterative = static_cast<double>(sumQuickIterative) / numTrials;


    // Return array containing average execution times
    return { averageQuickRecursive, averageQuickIterative};
}

int main() {
    int upperBound = 500;
    int numTrials = 5; // Number of trials for each input size

    // Create vectors to store execution times
    vector<double> quickRecursiveTimes;
    vector<double> quickIterativeTimes;

    quickRecursiveTimes.reserve(upperBound);
    quickIterativeTimes.reserve(upperBound);

    // Add time measurements to the vectors
    for (int i = 1; i <= upperBound; ++i) {
        // Generate vector with i random numbers
        vector<int> numbers = generateRandomVector(i);
        writeListToFile(numbers, numbers.size());

        // Get time measurements for each sorting algorithm
        array<double, 2> executionTimes = sortingComparison(numbers, numTrials);
        quickRecursiveTimes.push_back(executionTimes[0]);
        quickIterativeTimes.push_back(executionTimes[1]);
    }

    // Print the two lists
    cout << "Quick recursive time measurements (micro seconds): ";
    cout << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound - 1; ++i) {
        cout << quickRecursiveTimes[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << quickRecursiveTimes[upperBound - 1] << "]" << endl;

    cout << "Quick iterative time measurements (micro seconds): ";
    cout << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound - 1; ++i) {
        cout << quickIterativeTimes[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << quickIterativeTimes[upperBound - 1] << "]" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Python code for plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load the data from the text file
quick_recursive_times = []  # List of recursive time measurements
quick_iterative_times =  []  # List of iterative time measurements

# Generate x-axis values (list lengths)
x_values = np.arange(1, len(quick_recursive_times) + 1)

# Plot the merge recursive time measurements in blue
plt.plot(x_values, quick_recursive_times, color='blue', label='Quick sort recursive Approach')

# Plot the merge iterative time measurements in red
plt.plot(x_values, quick_iterative_times, color='red', label='Quick sort iterative Approach')

# Label the axes and title
plt.xlabel('List Length')
plt.ylabel('Time (micro seconds)')
plt.title('Sorting Execution Time Comparison')

# Add a legend
plt.legend()

# Show grid
plt.grid(True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Execution Time vs Input Size graph using Python

[image]

Comment: why do you expect one to be faster and the other to be slower?

Comment: I dont understand how `# Load the data from the text file quick_recursive_times = []` is supposed to help us for debugging. You should either post a [mcve] or factor out the plotting from the problem. Instead of plotting you could post a list of results, but if you want us to verify that the graph is correct you need to show how you create the graph

Comment: You do build with optimizations enabled I hope? Benchmarking unoptimized builds is rather useless. And only five measurements might be a little too small set to get any useful data.

Comment: Hi, you intuition is correct but it depends how it's really executed in terms of hardware. The iterative approaches are often working with the heap and recursion is with the stack and that is recursion is faster in practice due to cache misses up to the point stack overflow is reached. You could see this post also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209/recursion-or-iteration#answer-13775120

Comment: Oh and you need to copy the input data for *each* time you call the sorting functions. Right now the first iteration in `sortingComparison` will sort the data, then the other iterations will use the already sorted data, and sort it again. Sorting already sorted input is one corner-case where quicksort performs badly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with std::deque (used in your std::stack) could it be possible that the various pushes imply a runtime allocation overhead?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to correctly measure sorting times or how to plot some data with C++ or Python or gnuplot? These are two rather independent questions. How does your datafile look like? Please post some example lines.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I created two copies of the array and sorted them separately using the two approaches. Copying the *output data* from the C++ terminal to the Python code is the only time you need to copy something.

Comment: `void recursivequickSort(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high)` takes the vector by reference, you generate random input then sort it, then on each next iteration you sort again already sorted data. Same for the other algorithm. Thats where you should make a copy, because sorting already sorted data is not representative

Comment: Looking at the code I suspect that the iterative implementation is doing more work and in a way that isn't cache local, I'm curious about the high glitch on both graphs at around 470 items (not an obviously tricky number). Be worth scaling the x axis in powers of 2 and going just past 512 just in case something interesting happens. As for GNUplot getting your very first graph out of it is something of a rite of passage but it gets much easier after that. The learning curve is quite steep though! Save the first script that you get to work!

Comment: In the `sortingComparison` you call the sorting functions in a loop. After the first iteration of that loop, the input data will be sorted. Now what happens when the loop continues to iterate? How is the input data (in `recursiveArr` and `iterativeArr`) arranged for all other iterations of the loop? How and when will you get the original unsorted input data into those vectors again? Or will they stay sorted?

Comment: I tested iterative versus recursive with C++ programs, where I used an array with index for the iterative stack. For large arrays (like 16 to 64 million elements), I'm not seeing a significant difference in time to sort, since most of the time is spent doing partition steps. 16 million elements takes less than 2 seconds, so there isn't much practical use for benchmarking smaller arrays like 1 million elements or less.